# Convert a list to a data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a nested list of data. Its length is 132 and each item is a list of length 20. Is there a *quick* way to convert this structure into a data frame that has 132 rows and 20 columns of data?

Here is some sample data to work with:

```
l <- replicate(
  132,
  as.list(sample(letters, 20)),
  simplify = FALSE
)
```

Comment: So you want each list element as a row of data in your data.frame?

Comment: @RichieCotton It's not right example. "each item is a **list** of length 20" and you got each item is a one element list of **vector** of length 20.

Comment: Late to the party, but I didn't see anyone mention [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/concatenating-a-list-of-data-frames/), which I thought was very handy (for what I was looking to do).

Comment: See also [Most efficient list to data.frame method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942760/most-efficient-list-to-data-frame-method)

Comment: mentioned in https://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-a-list-to-a-data-frame/

Comment: bind_rows(l) is "is an efficient implementation of the common pattern of do.call(rbind, dfs)" (simplest answer, wraps Marek's answer)

Answer (score 481, accepted):

**Update July 2020:**

The default for the parameter `stringsAsFactors` is now `default.stringsAsFactors()` which in turn yields `FALSE` as its default.

---

Assuming your list of lists is called `l`:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(l), nrow=length(l), byrow=TRUE))
```

The above will convert all character columns to factors, to avoid this you can add a parameter to the data.frame() call:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(l), nrow=132, byrow=TRUE),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Careful here if your data is not all of the same type. Passing through a matrix means that all data will be coerced into a common type. I.e. if you have one column of character data and one column of numeric data the numeric data will be coerced to string by matrix() and then both to factor by data.frame().

Comment: What is the best way to do this where the list has missing values, or to include NA in the data frame?

Comment: @Dave: I don't think I quite follow you... this works even if there are NAs around...

Comment: @nico for me if there was a ragged data frame, it wouldnt incorporate NA

Comment: @nico must be because mine isnt a matrix, its a data frame

Comment: @Dave: note that I am outputting a data frame, not a matrix. I pass through a matrix just to split the data onto columns. Anyway, maybe it is better to post a new question with more details and a reproducible example. :)

Comment: Also take care if you have character data type - data.frame will convert it to factors.

Comment: @mropa's answer is far superior, since it's simpler and preserves data types.

Comment: @mropas answer doesn't work with the sample in the question. It works with it's own sample data. Of all the answer only this one gets the correct result.

Comment: @VickyZhang well, I'm not too well versed in Python to be honest (I didn't know it had data frame at all for instance...). In any case you can probably list a series of other things that are longer in Python than in R, but that means pretty much nothing. They are different languages built for different purposes. And, above all, it's a one-liner, it does not seem that complicated to me.

Comment: @nico Is there a way to keep the list elements names as colnames or rownames in the df?

Comment: To make it more dynamic you'd might write `nrow = length(l)` instead of `nrow = 132`.

Comment: This answer is quite old, but maybe this is useful for somebody else (also @N.Varela asked for it):

If you wanna keep the list element names, try ```names(df) <- names(unlist(l[1]))``` after using above command.

Answer (score 617):

With `rbind`

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, your_list)
```

Edit: Previous version return `data.frame` of `list`'s instead of vectors (as @IanSudbery pointed out in comments).

Comment: Why does this work but `rbind(your_list)` returns a 1x32 list matrix?

Comment: @eykanal `do.call` pass elements of `your_list` as arguments to `rbind`. It's equivalent of `rbind(your_list[[1]], your_list[[2]], your_list[[3]], ....., your_list[[length of your_list]])`.

Comment: This method suffers from the null situation.

Comment: @FrankWANG But this method is not designed to null situation. It's required that `your_list` contain equally sized vectors. `NULL` has length 0 so it should failed.

Comment: This method seems to return the correct object, but on inspecting the object, you'll find that the columns are lists rather than vectors, which can lead to problems down the line if you are not expecting it.

Comment: doesn't work with the sample data provided in the question

Comment: @MySchizoBuddy Example added recently is not consistent with original description in question.

Comment: Sort of minor gripe, but this returns a list when it should be returning a data frame. Fortunately, you can call as.data.frame() on the return of do.call() and it will format correctly as a data.frame object.

Comment: @JohnH. It should return `data.frame`. Could you provide example?

Comment: Neat solution Marek especially because it takes column and row names (which the unlist solution doesn't). The output I got was a numeric DF - so no involuntary factor conversion. Thanks!

Comment: bind_rows is "is an efficient implementation of the common pattern of do.call(rbind, dfs)"

Comment: To ensure that characters are not converted to factors use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. This is done using the args input as: `do.call(rbind.data.frame, args = list(your_list, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Answer (score 165):

You can use the `plyr` package.
For example a nested list of the form

```
l <- list(a = list(var.1 = 1, var.2 = 2, var.3 = 3)
      , b = list(var.1 = 4, var.2 = 5, var.3 = 6)
      , c = list(var.1 = 7, var.2 = 8, var.3 = 9)
      , d = list(var.1 = 10, var.2 = 11, var.3 = 12)
      )
```

has now a length of 4 and each list in `l` contains another list of the length 3.
Now you can run

```
  library (plyr)
  df <- ldply (l, data.frame)
```

and should get the same result as in the answer @Marek and @nico.

Comment: Great answer. I could you explain a little how that works? It simply returns a data frame for each list entry?

Comment: Imho the BEST answer. It returns a honest data.frame. All the data types (character, numeric, etc) are correctly transformed. If the list has different data types their will be all transformed to character with `matrix` approach.

Comment: the sample provided here isn't the one provided by the question. the result of this answer on the original dataset is incorrect.

Comment: Works great for me! And the names of the columns in the resulting Data Frame are set! Tx

Comment: Is plyr multicore? Or is there a lapply version for use with mclapply?

Comment: plyr is being deprecated in favour of dplyr

Answer (score 135):

Fixing the sample data so it matches the original description 'each item is a list of length 20'

```
mylistlist <- replicate(
  132,
  as.list(sample(letters, 20)),
  simplify = FALSE
)
```

we can convert it to a data frame like this:

```
data.frame(t(sapply(mylistlist,c)))
```

`sapply` converts it to a matrix.
`data.frame` converts the matrix to a data frame.

resulting in:

[image]

Comment: best answer by far! None of the other solutions get the types/column names correct. THANK YOU!

Comment: What role are you intending `c` to play here, one instance of the list's data? Oh wait, c for the concatenate function right? Getting confused with @mnel's usage of c. I also concur with @dchandler, getting the column names right was a valuable need in my use case. Brilliant solution.

Comment: that right - standard c function; from `?c` : `Combine Values into a Vector or List`

Comment: doesn't work with the sample data provided in the question

Comment: Someone (not the originator) changed the question. Should be changed back.

Comment: Doesn't this generate a data.frame of lists?

Comment: @Carl why are you asking? What result did you get?

Comment: It works but df$id returns a list instead of a dataframe.

Comment: and if the length of the list are diferent ?

Answer (score 89):

assume your list is called `L`,

```
data.frame(Reduce(rbind, L))
```

Comment: Nice one! There is one difference with @Alex Brown's solution compared to yours, going your route yielded the following warning message for some reason: `Warning message:
In data.row.names(row.names, rowsi, i) :
  some row.names duplicated: 3,4 --> row.names NOT used'

Comment: Very good!! Worked for me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996321/rearranging-list-into-data-frame?noredirect=1#comment53817556_32996321

Comment: Works well unless the list has only one element in it: `data.frame(Reduce(rbind, list(c('col1','col2'))))` produces a data frame with **2 rows, 1 column** (I expected 1 row 2 columns)

Comment: Instead of using the base function "Reduce" you can use the purr function "reduce" as in: `reduce(L, rbind)`. This outputs a single dataframe and assumes that each data frame in your list (L) is organized the same way (i.e. contains the same number of columns in the same order.

Answer (score 70):

The package `data.table` has the function `rbindlist` which is a superfast implementation of `do.call(rbind, list(...))`.

It can take a list of  `lists`, `data.frames` or `data.tables`  as input.

```
library(data.table)
ll <- list(a = list(var.1 = 1, var.2 = 2, var.3 = 3)
  , b = list(var.1 = 4, var.2 = 5, var.3 = 6)
  , c = list(var.1 = 7, var.2 = 8, var.3 = 9)
  , d = list(var.1 = 10, var.2 = 11, var.3 = 12)
  )

DT <- rbindlist(ll)
```

This returns a `data.table` inherits from `data.frame`.

If you ***really*** want to convert back to a data.frame use `as.data.frame(DT)`

Comment: Regarding the last line, `setDF` now allows for returning to data.frame by reference.

Comment: For my list with 30k items, rbindlist worked way faster than ldply

Comment: This is indeed super fast!

Comment: This was just what the doctor ordered - thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Answer (score 56):

The `tibble` package has a function `enframe()` that solves this problem by coercing nested `list` objects to nested `tibble` ("tidy" data frame) objects. Here's a brief example from [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#creating-list-columns):

```
x <- list(
    a = 1:5,
    b = 3:4, 
    c = 5:6
) 

df <- enframe(x)
df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>    name     value
#>   <chr>    <list>
#>    1     a <int [5]>
#>    2     b <int [2]>
#>    3     c <int [2]>
```

Since you have several nests in your list, `l`, you can use the `unlist(recursive = FALSE)` to remove unnecessary nesting to get just a single hierarchical list and then pass to `enframe()`. I use `tidyr::unnest()` to unnest the output into a single level "tidy" data frame, which has your two columns (one for the group `name` and one for the observations with the groups `value`). If you want columns that make wide, you can add a column using `add_column()` that just repeats the order of the values 132 times. Then just `spread()` the values.

```r
library(tidyverse)

l <- replicate(
    132,
    list(sample(letters, 20)),
    simplify = FALSE
)

l_tib <- l %>% 
    unlist(recursive = FALSE) %>% 
    enframe() %>% 
    unnest()
l_tib
#> # A tibble: 2,640 x 2
#>     name value
#>    <int> <chr>
#> 1      1     d
#> 2      1     z
#> 3      1     l
#> 4      1     b
#> 5      1     i
#> 6      1     j
#> 7      1     g
#> 8      1     w
#> 9      1     r
#> 10     1     p
#> # ... with 2,630 more rows

l_tib_spread <- l_tib %>%
    add_column(index = rep(1:20, 132)) %>%
    spread(key = index, value = value)
l_tib_spread
#> # A tibble: 132 x 21
#>     name   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  `11`
#> *  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1      1     d     z     l     b     i     j     g     w     r     p     y
#> 2      2     w     s     h     r     i     k     d     u     a     f     j
#> 3      3     r     v     q     s     m     u     j     p     f     a     i
#> 4      4     o     y     x     n     p     i     f     m     h     l     t
#> 5      5     p     w     v     d     k     a     l     r     j     q     n
#> 6      6     i     k     w     o     c     n     m     b     v     e     q
#> 7      7     c     d     m     i     u     o     e     z     v     g     p
#> 8      8     f     s     e     o     p     n     k     x     c     z     h
#> 9      9     d     g     o     h     x     i     c     y     t     f     j
#> 10    10     y     r     f     k     d     o     b     u     i     x     s
#> # ... with 122 more rows, and 9 more variables: `12` <chr>, `13` <chr>,
#> #   `14` <chr>, `15` <chr>, `16` <chr>, `17` <chr>, `18` <chr>,
#> #   `19` <chr>, `20` <chr>
```

Comment: Quoting the OP: "Is there a quick way to convert this structure into a data frame that has 132 rows and 20 columns of data?" So maybe you need a spread step or something.

Comment: Ah yes, there just needs to be an index column that can be spread. I will update shortly.

Answer (score 36):

Depending on the structure of your lists there are some `tidyverse` options that work nicely with unequal length lists:

```
l <- list(a = list(var.1 = 1, var.2 = 2, var.3 = 3)
        , b = list(var.1 = 4, var.2 = 5)
        , c = list(var.1 = 7, var.3 = 9)
        , d = list(var.1 = 10, var.2 = 11, var.3 = NA))

df <- dplyr::bind_rows(l)
df <- purrr::map_df(l, dplyr::bind_rows)
df <- purrr::map_df(l, ~.x)

# all create the same data frame:
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  var.1 var.2 var.3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3
2     4     5    NA
3     7    NA     9
4    10    11    NA
```

You can also mix vectors and data frames:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(
  list(a = 1, b = 2),
  data_frame(a = 3:4, b = 5:6),
  c(a = 7)
)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
2     3     5
3     4     6
4     7    NA
```

Comment: This dplyr::bind_rows function works well, even with hard to work with lists originating as JSON.  From JSON to a surprisingly clean dataframe.  Nice.

Comment: @sbha I tried to use df <- purrr::map_df(l, ~.x) but it seems like its not working , the error message i have is Error: Column `X2` can't be converted from integer to character

Answer (score 30):

This method uses a `tidyverse` package (**purrr**).

The list:

```
x <- as.list(mtcars)
```

Converting it into a data frame (a `tibble` more specifically):

```
library(purrr)
map_df(x, ~.x)
```

## EDIT: May 30, 2021

This can actually be achieved with the `bind_rows()` function in `dplyr`.

```
x <- as.list(mtcars)
dplyr::bind_rows(x)

 A tibble: 32 x 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Answer (score 17):

Reshape2 yields the same output as the plyr example above:

```
library(reshape2)
l <- list(a = list(var.1 = 1, var.2 = 2, var.3 = 3)
          , b = list(var.1 = 4, var.2 = 5, var.3 = 6)
          , c = list(var.1 = 7, var.2 = 8, var.3 = 9)
          , d = list(var.1 = 10, var.2 = 11, var.3 = 12)
)
l <- melt(l)
dcast(l, L1 ~ L2)
```

yields:

```
  L1 var.1 var.2 var.3
1  a     1     2     3
2  b     4     5     6
3  c     7     8     9
4  d    10    11    12
```

If you were almost out of pixels you *could* do this all in 1 line w/ recast().

Comment: I think reshape2 is being deprecated for dplyr, tidyr, etc

Answer (score 13):

Extending on @Marek's answer: if you want to avoid strings to be turned into factors and efficiency is not a concern try

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(your_list, data.frame, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 12):

For the general case of deeply nested lists **with 3 or more levels** like the ones obtained from a nested JSON:

```
{
"2015": {
  "spain": {"population": 43, "GNP": 9},
  "sweden": {"population": 7, "GNP": 6}},
"2016": {
  "spain": {"population": 45, "GNP": 10},
  "sweden": {"population": 9, "GNP": 8}}
}
```

consider the approach of `melt()` to convert the nested list to a tall format first:

```
myjson <- jsonlite:fromJSON(file("test.json"))
tall <- reshape2::melt(myjson)[, c("L1", "L2", "L3", "value")]
    L1     L2         L3 value
1 2015  spain population    43
2 2015  spain        GNP     9
3 2015 sweden population     7
4 2015 sweden        GNP     6
5 2016  spain population    45
6 2016  spain        GNP    10
7 2016 sweden population     9
8 2016 sweden        GNP     8
```

followed by `dcast()` then to wide again into a tidy dataset where each variable forms a a column and each observation forms a row:

```
wide <- reshape2::dcast(tall, L1+L2~L3) 
# left side of the formula defines the rows/observations and the 
# right side defines the variables/measurements
    L1     L2 GNP population
1 2015  spain   9         43
2 2015 sweden   6          7
3 2016  spain  10         45
4 2016 sweden   8          9
```

Answer (score 11):

The following simple command worked for me:

```
myDf <- as.data.frame(myList)
```

Reference ([Quora answer](https://qr.ae/TWTsim))

```
> myList <- list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6))
> myList
$a
[1] 1 2 3
 
$b
[1] 4 5 6
 
> myDf <- as.data.frame(myList)
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
> class(myDf)
[1] "data.frame"
```

But this will fail if it’s not obvious how to convert the list to a data frame:

```
> myList <- list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6, 7))
> myDf <- as.data.frame(myList)
```

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 4

**Note**: The answer is toward the title of the question and may skips some details of the question

Comment: A note that on the input from the question this only sort of works. OP asks for 132 rows and 20 columns, but this gives 20 rows and 132 columns.

Comment: For your example with different-length input where it fails, it's not clear what the desired result would be...

Comment: @Gregor True, but the question title is "R - list to data frame". Many visitors of the question and those who voted it up don't have the exact problem of OP. Based on the question title, they just look for a way to convert list to data frame. I myself had the same problem and the solution I posted solved my problem

Comment: Yup, just noting. Not downvoting. It might be nice to note in the answer that it does something similar--but distinctly different than--pretty much all the other answers.

Answer (score 10):

More answers, along with timings in the answer to this question:
[What is the most efficient way to cast a list as a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512465/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-cast-a-list-as-a-data-frame?rq=1)

The quickest way, that doesn't produce a dataframe with lists rather than vectors for columns appears to be (from Martin Morgan's answer):

```
l <- list(list(col1="a",col2=1),list(col1="b",col2=2))
f = function(x) function(i) unlist(lapply(x, `[[`, i), use.names=FALSE)
as.data.frame(Map(f(l), names(l[[1]])))
```

Answer (score 9):

If your list has elements with the same dimensions, you could use the `bind_rows` function from the tidyverse.

```
# Load the tidyverse
Library(tidyverse)

# make a list with elements having same dimensions
My_list <- list(a = c(1, 4, 5), b = c(9, 3, 8))

## Bind the rows
My_list %>% bind_rows()
```

The result is a data frame with two rows.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the simplest solution. I tried all other solutions but none worked. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: How do you keep each sublist as a column name?

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes your data may be a list of lists of vectors of the same length.

```
lolov = list(list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)), list(c(7,8,9),c(10,11,12),c(13,14,15)) )
```

(The inner vectors could also be lists, but I'm simplifying to make this easier to read).

Then you can make the following modification. Remember that you can unlist one level at a time:

```
lov = unlist(lolov, recursive = FALSE )
> lov
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 7 8 9

[[4]]
[1] 10 11 12

[[5]]
[1] 13 14 15
```

Now use your favorite method mentioned in the other answers:

```
library(plyr)
>ldply(lov)
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
4 10 11 12
5 13 14 15
```

Comment: plyr is being deprecated in favour of dplyr

Answer (score 4):

This is what finally worked for me:

`do.call("rbind", lapply(S1, as.data.frame))`

Answer (score 4):

A short (but perhaps not the fastest) way to do this would be to use base r, since a data frame is just a [list of equal length vectors](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html). Thus the conversion between your input list and a 30 x 132 data.frame would be:

```
df <- data.frame(l)
```

From there we can transpose it to a 132 x 30 matrix, and convert it back to a dataframe:

```
new_df <- data.frame(t(df))
```

As a one-liner:

```
new_df <- data.frame(t(data.frame(l)))
```

The rownames will be pretty annoying to look at, but you could always rename those with

`rownames(new_df) <- 1:nrow(new_df)`

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I'd like to know so I don't continue to spread misinformation.

Comment: I've definitely done this before, using a combination of data.frame and t! I guess the people who downvoted feel there are better ways, particularly those that don't mess up the names.

Comment: That's a good point, I guess this is also incorrect if you want to preserve names in your list.

Answer (score 4):

For a paralleled (multicore, multisession, etc) solution using `purrr` family of solutions, use:

```
library (furrr)
plan(multisession) # see below to see which other plan() is the more efficient
myTibble <- future_map_dfc(l, ~.x)
```

Where `l` is the list.

To benchmark the most efficient `plan()` you can use:

```
library(tictoc)
plan(sequential) # reference time
# plan(multisession) # benchamark plan() goes here. See ?plan().
tic()
myTibble <- future_map_dfc(l, ~.x)
toc()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l <- replicate(10,list(sample(letters, 20)))
a <-lapply(l[1:10],data.frame)
do.call("cbind", a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Every solution I have found seems to only apply when every object in a `list` has the same `length`.  I needed to convert a `list` to a `data.frame` when the `length` of the objects in the `list` were of unequal `length`.  Below is the base `R` solution I came up with.  It no doubt is very inefficient, but it does seem to work.

```
x1 <- c(2, 13)
x2 <- c(2, 4, 6, 9, 11, 13)
x3 <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13)
my.results <- list(x1, x2, x3)

# identify length of each list
my.lengths <- unlist(lapply(my.results, function (x) { length(unlist(x))}))
my.lengths
#[1]  2  6 20

# create a vector of values in all lists
my.values <- as.numeric(unlist(c(do.call(rbind, lapply(my.results, as.data.frame)))))
my.values
#[1]  2 13  2  4  6  9 11 13  1  1  2  3  3  4  5  5  6  7  7  8  9  9 10 11 11 12 13 13

my.matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = max(my.lengths), ncol = length(my.lengths))

my.cumsum <- cumsum(my.lengths)

mm <- 1

for(i in 1:length(my.lengths)) {

     my.matrix[1:my.lengths[i],i] <- my.values[mm:my.cumsum[i]]

     mm <- my.cumsum[i]+1

}

my.df <- as.data.frame(my.matrix)
my.df
#   V1 V2 V3
#1   2  2  1
#2  13  4  1
#3  NA  6  2
#4  NA  9  3
#5  NA 11  3
#6  NA 13  4
#7  NA NA  5
#8  NA NA  5
#9  NA NA  6
#10 NA NA  7
#11 NA NA  7
#12 NA NA  8
#13 NA NA  9
#14 NA NA  9
#15 NA NA 10
#16 NA NA 11
#17 NA NA 11
#18 NA NA 12
#19 NA NA 13
#20 NA NA 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `collapse::unlist2d` (shorthand for 'unlist to data.frame'):

```
l <- replicate(
  132,
  list(sample(letters, 20)),
  simplify = FALSE
)

library(collapse)
head(unlist2d(l))
  .id.1 .id.2 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20
1     1     1  e  x  b  d  s  p  a  c  k   z   q   m   u   l   h   n   r   t   o   y
2     2     1  r  t  i  k  m  b  h  n  s   e   p   f   o   c   x   l   g   v   a   j
3     3     1  t  r  v  z  a  u  c  o  w   f   m   b   d   g   p   q   y   e   n   k
4     4     1  x  i  e  p  f  d  q  k  h   b   j   s   z   a   t   v   y   l   m   n
5     5     1  d  z  k  y  a  p  b  h  c   v   f   m   u   l   n   q   e   i   w   j
6     6     1  l  f  s  u  o  v  p  z  q   e   r   c   h   n   a   t   m   k   y   x

head(unlist2d(l, idcols = FALSE))
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20
1  e  x  b  d  s  p  a  c  k   z   q   m   u   l   h   n   r   t   o   y
2  r  t  i  k  m  b  h  n  s   e   p   f   o   c   x   l   g   v   a   j
3  t  r  v  z  a  u  c  o  w   f   m   b   d   g   p   q   y   e   n   k
4  x  i  e  p  f  d  q  k  h   b   j   s   z   a   t   v   y   l   m   n
5  d  z  k  y  a  p  b  h  c   v   f   m   u   l   n   q   e   i   w   j
6  l  f  s  u  o  v  p  z  q   e   r   c   h   n   a   t   m   k   y   x
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `map_` function together with a `for` loop? Here is my solution:

```
list_to_df <- function(list_to_convert) {
  tmp_data_frame <- data.frame()
  for (i in 1:length(list_to_convert)) {
    tmp <- map_dfr(list_to_convert[[i]], data.frame)
    tmp_data_frame <- rbind(tmp_data_frame, tmp)
  }
  return(tmp_data_frame)
}
```

where `map_dfr` convert each of the list element into a data.frame and then `rbind` union them altogether.

In your case, I guess it would be:

```
converted_list <- list_to_df(l)
```

Comment: 1. Results are wrong 2. The loop is unefficient. Better use nested map: `map(list_to_convert, ~map_dfr(., data.frame))` but still it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the tibble package (from tidyverse):

```
#create examplelist
l <- replicate(
  132,
  as.list(sample(letters, 20)),
  simplify = FALSE
)

#package tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

#make a dataframe (or use as_tibble)
df <- as_data_frame(l,.name_repair = "unique")
```

Comment: It creates df with 20 rows and 132 columns but it should be otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest this solution as well. Although it looks similar to other solutions, it uses rbind.fill from the plyr package. This is advantageous in situations where a list has missing columns or NA values.

```
l <- replicate(10,as.list(sample(letters,10)),simplify = FALSE)

res<-data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(l))
  res<-plyr::rbind.fill(res,data.frame(t(unlist(l[i]))))

res
```

Answer (score 0):

From a different perspective;

```
install.packages("smotefamily")
library(smotefamily)
library(dplyr)

data_example = sample_generator(5000,ratio = 0.80)
genData = BLSMOTE(data_example[,-3],data_example[,3])
#There are many lists in genData. If we want to convert one of them to dataframe.

sentetic=as.data.frame.array(genData$syn_data)
# as.data.frame.array seems to be working.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```r
do.call(rbind, list(...))
```

I used:

```r
do.call(bind_rows, list(...))
```