# How to convert a list of lists to a dataframe - non-identical lists

Tags: r

I have a list where each element is a named list, but the elements are not the same everywhere. I have read solutions on how to convert lists of lists to dataframes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512465/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-cast-a-list-as-a-data-frame?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame), but none of this works when the lists are not identical.

Example - note I have mixed types as well, it is fine if the solution coerces everything to character.

```
lisnotOK <- list(list(a=1, b=2, c="hi"), list(b=2, c="hello", d="nope"))
```

The result should simply have NA where a column cannot be filled by a list, just like `rbind.fill` from plyr, or `rbind_all` from dplyr.

Example

```
lisOK <- list(list(a=1, b=2, c="hi"), list(a=3, b=5, c="bye"))

# One of many solutions
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lisOK)

# gives
   a b   c
2  1 2  hi
21 3 5 bye
```

Any solution that uses `rbind`, or tries to make `lisnotOK` into a matrix will fail, whereas any examples in the posts linked above don't work, even when I try to use `rbind_all` or `rbind.fill`.

One solution is an ugly for loop where each successive list is changed to a dataframe, and uses `rbind_all` to bind to a dataframe.

Does anyone know an efficient solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any function using `data.frame(.)` on each element of the list before binding would be terribly inefficient (not to mention unnecessary). Here's another way using `data.table`'s `rbindlist` (from v1.9.3) which you can get [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table).

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.3
rbindlist(lisnotOK, fill=TRUE)
#     a b     c    d
# 1:  1 2    hi   NA
# 2: NA 2 hello nope
```

It works on list-of-lists (as in this question), data.frames and data.tables.

If not this, then I'd go with Ananda's `list2mat` function (if your types are all identical).

---

Benchmarks on Ananda's `L2` data:

```
fun1 <- function(inList) ldply(inList, as.data.frame)
fun2 <- function(inList) list2mat(inList)
fun3 <- function(inList) rbindlist(inList, fill=TRUE)
fun4 <- function(inList) rbind_all(lapply(inList, as.data.frame))

microbenchmark(fun1(L2), fun2(L2), fun3(L2), fun4(L2), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr         min          lq      median          uq         max neval
#  fun1(L2) 1927.857847 2161.432665 2221.999940 2276.241366 2366.649614    10
#  fun2(L2)   12.039652   12.167613   12.361629   12.483751   16.040885    10
#  fun3(L2)    1.225929    1.374395    1.473621    1.510876    1.858597    10
#  fun4(L2) 1435.153576 1457.053482 1492.334965 1548.547706 1630.443430    10
```

Note: I've used `as.data.frame(.)` instead of `data.frame(.)` (former is slightly faster).

Comment: Thanks for the updated benchmarks. I didn't realize that `rbindlist` worked this way--or is that an update in 1.9.3 (and hence your specifying the version number)?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, `rbind` has `fill=TRUE` since 1.9.2, but it was implemented in R. In 1.9.3, everything was moved to C, and `rbindlsit` was embellished. You can read more [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/cb3f15cff04c4463de7dc92a2871a7767a3885f3).

Comment: hurray for `fill=TRUE` argument in rbindlist!

Answer (score 9):

Considering that you are OK with the resulting matrix being all of the same type (say, `character`), you can try to write your own function, like this:

```
list2mat <- function(inList) {
  UL <- unlist(inList)
  Nam <- unique(names(UL))
  M <- matrix(NA_character_, 
              nrow = length(inList), ncol = length(Nam), 
              dimnames = list(NULL, Nam))
  Row <- rep(seq_along(inList), sapply(inList, length))
  Col <- match(names(UL), Nam)
  M[cbind(Row, Col)] <- UL
  M
}
```

Usage would be:

```
list2mat(lisnotOK)
#      a   b   c       d     
# [1,] "1" "2" "hi"    NA    
# [2,] NA  "2" "hello" "nope"
```

This *should* be pretty fast since everything is pre-allocated and you are making use of matrix indexing.

---

#### Update: Benchmarks (since you said efficiency was a concern)

```
fun1 <- function(inList) ldply(inList, data.frame)
fun2 <- function(inList) list2mat(inList)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(lisnotOK), fun2(lisnotOK))
# Unit: microseconds
#            expr      min        lq    median       uq      max neval
#  fun1(lisnotOK) 4193.808 4340.0585 4523.3000 4912.233 7600.341   100
#  fun2(lisnotOK)  163.784  182.3865  211.2515  236.910  363.489   100

L2 <- unlist(replicate(1000, lisnotOK, simplify=FALSE), recursive=FALSE)
microbenchmark(fun1(L2), fun2(L2), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
#  fun1(L2) 3032.71572 3106.79006 3196.17178 3306.11756 3609.67445    10
#  fun2(L2)   24.16817   24.86991   25.65569   27.44128   29.41908    10
```

Comment: +1.  It's a huge difference.  Not sure if this work with `rbindlist(,fill=TRUE).  I don't have the new version of data.table to test.

Answer (score 6):

Use `lapply` to convert your list elements to `data.frame`s and `rbind_all` that:

```
rbind_all(lapply(lisnotOK,data.frame))
   a b     c    d
1  1 2    hi <NA>
2 NA 2 hello nope
Warning message:
In rbind_all(lapply(lisnotOK, data.frame)) :
  Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
```

Or from `plyr`, `ldply` with `data.frame`:

```
ldply(lisnotOK,data.frame)
   a b     c    d
1  1 2    hi <NA>
2 NA 2 hello nope
```

Comment: This is very nice, unfortunately I just found it does not work on my actual list as some elements contain NULL. But that's easy to fix in another lapply.

Comment: @akrun, why? What's special about `ldply`?

Comment: @akrun, that's because you're not looking at the code for `ldply`. By that logic, my code is just `list2mat(lisnotOK)` :-)