# R: Merge lists containing vectors and scalars

Tags: r

I have `N` lists that have some identical column names. Here is a MWE with two list:

```
ls <- list()
ls[[1]] <- list("a"=1:2,
                "b"=20,
                "c"=numeric(0))
names(ls[[1]]$a) <- c("a1", "a2")

ls[[2]] <- list("a"=3:4,
                "b"=30,
                "c"=1:4,
                "d"="f")
names(ls[[2]]$a) <- c("a1", "a2")
```

Is it possible merge these into a resulting list `lsRes`, where `lsRes` has the following properties:

1. `lsRes$a` contains two elements, where the first is the named vector
   c(1,2) (with names c(a1, a2)) and the second a named vector c(3,4)
   (with names (c(a1.a2)))
2. `lsRes$b` contains two elements, where the first is 20 and the second is 30
3. `lsRes$c` contains two elements, where the first is numeric(0) and the second is 1:4
4. `lsRes$d` contains
   two elements, where the first is NA and the second is "f"

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609112/how-to-convert-a-list-of-lists-to-a-dataframe-non-identical-lists) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308551/do-callrbind-list-for-uneven-number-of-column), but they describe different cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we need to have the output also as a `list`, we create the common `names` and then assign those doesn't any of the common names to `NA`

```
nm1 <- unique(unlist(sapply(ls, names)))
lsRes <- lapply(ls, function(x) {x[setdiff(nm1, names(x))] <- NA; x})
lengths(lsRes)
#[1] 4 4
```

If we need to have a `list` of 4 elements, then use `transpose`

```
library(purrr)
lsRes %>%
      transpose
```

Comment: Thanks. but isn't `lsRes` identical to `ls`?

Comment: @N08 I has the additional element for 'd'.  Do u want a list output or somethign else?

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to merge the lists together now so the four conditions above are satisfied?

Comment: @N08 Do u need a data.frame as output?  It is not clear about how the output would look like

Comment: Yes, a data.frame

Comment: For the `a`, there are 2 elements each for each list element, but 'b' have both  single element, `c` with one element as numeric(0) etc.  Can u show the expected output in your post

Comment: I tried to describe it with the numbered list in my OP. Should I elaborate?

Comment: @N08  Thanks, I read that part, but I am not sure how the output you wanted as a data.frame

Comment: it seems I can't convert it to a data.frame due to the following being illegal: `lsRes$a[[1]] = named vector c(1,2)`. Maybe a list is the way to go?

Comment: @N08 It is better to store it in a list, but it can be converted if you show what exactly you are expecting