# Most efficient list to data.frame method?

Tags: performance, r, memory-management, dataframe, data.table

Just had a conversation with coworkers about this, and we thought it'd be worth seeing what people out in SO land had to say.  Suppose I had a list with N elements, where each element was a vector of length X.  Now suppose I wanted to transform that into a data.frame.  As with most things in R, there are multiple ways of skinning the proverbial cat, such as `as.dataframe`, using the plyr package, comboing `do.call` with `cbind`, pre-allocating the DF and filling it in, and others.

The problem that was presented was what happens when either N or X (in our case it is X) becomes extremely large.  Is there one cat skinning method that's notably superior when efficiency (particularly in terms of memory) is of the essence?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since a `data.frame` is already a list and you know that each list element is the same length (X), the fastest thing would probably be to just update the `class` and `row.names` attributes:

```
set.seed(21)
n <- 1e6
x <- list(x=rnorm(n), y=rnorm(n), z=rnorm(n))
x <- c(x,x,x,x,x,x)

system.time(a <- as.data.frame(x))
system.time(b <- do.call(data.frame,x))
system.time({
  d <- x  # Skip 'c' so Joris doesn't down-vote me! ;-)
  class(d) <- "data.frame"
  rownames(d) <- 1:n
  names(d) <- make.unique(names(d))
})

identical(a, b)  # TRUE
identical(b, d)  # TRUE
```

**Update** - this is ~2x faster than creating `d`:

```
system.time({
  e <- x
  attr(e, "row.names") <- c(NA_integer_,n)
  attr(e, "class") <- "data.frame"
  attr(e, "names") <- make.names(names(e), unique=TRUE)
})

identical(d, e)  # TRUE
```

**Update 2** - I forgot about memory consumption.  The last update makes two copies of `e`.  Using the `attributes` function reduces that to only one copy.

```
set.seed(21)
f <- list(x=rnorm(n), y=rnorm(n), z=rnorm(n))
f <- c(f,f,f,f,f,f)
tracemem(f)
system.time({  # makes 2 copies
  attr(f, "row.names") <- c(NA_integer_,n)
  attr(f, "class") <- "data.frame"
  attr(f, "names") <- make.names(names(f), unique=TRUE)
})

set.seed(21)
g <- list(x=rnorm(n), y=rnorm(n), z=rnorm(n))
g <- c(g,g,g,g,g,g)
tracemem(g)
system.time({  # only makes 1 copy
  attributes(g) <- list(row.names=c(NA_integer_,n),
    class="data.frame", names=make.names(names(g), unique=TRUE))
})

identical(f,g)  # TRUE
```

Comment: Leave "probably" out of the answer and it's correct.  It's also correct if you make a function using those calls and replacing the cheat of knowing n with a length command.  Your new function is roughly equivalent to data.frame() after removing all of the extensive checks.  So, if you know for sure you're handing the call the right input then just do what Josh recommended for speed.  If you're unsure then data.frame is safer and, do.call(data.frame, x)) is next fastest (oddly enough).

Comment: See `plyr::quickdf` for exactly this function.

Comment: @hadley: `plyr::quickdf` doesn't provide exactly this function; namely it doesn't make unique column names. `plyr:::make_names` only replaces missing names and doesn't have a `unique=` arg like `base::make.names`.

Comment: @John: By "probably" I meant "to the best of my knowledge".  I try not to speak too strongly if I'm not absolutely certain.

Comment: Ok, not exactly, but pretty close (unique column names aren't a prerequisite for a valid data frame).  I'm not sure that memory hacks based on undocumented behaviour of `attributes<-` are a good idea.

Comment: @hadley: what memory hacks?  I was merely pointing out that 1 call to `attributes<-` makes fewer copies than 3 calls to `attr<-`.

Comment: Nice demo of `tracemem` in action, and a good illustration of the difference between lists and data frames.

Comment: @Joshua : +1 for skipping c ;)

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted your answer - `structure` is the canonical way of returning an object with modified attributes.

Comment: @hadley: canonical according to whom?  I can't find any discussion of that in the manuals and `attr<-` and `structure` seem to be used about equally often in the core R sources... and `structure` uses `attributes<-`.

Answer (score 10):

This appears to need a `data.table` suggestion given that efficiency for large datasets is required. Notably `setattr` sets by reference and does not copy

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(21)
n <- 1e6
h <- list(x=rnorm(n), y=rnorm(n), z=rnorm(n))
h <- c(h,h,h,h,h,h)
tracemem(h)

system.time({h <- as.data.table(h)
            setattr(h, 'names', make.names(names(h), unique=T))})
```

`as.data.table`, however does make a copy.

---

## Edit - no copying version

Using @MatthewDowle's suggestion `setattr(h,'class','data.frame')` which will convert to data.frame by reference (**no copies**)

```
set.seed(21)
n <- 1e6
i <- list(x=rnorm(n), y=rnorm(n), z=rnorm(n))
i <- c(i,i,i,i,i,i)
tracemem(i)

system.time({  
  setattr(i, 'class', 'data.frame')
  setattr(i, "row.names", c(NA_integer_,n))

  setattr(i, "names", make.names(names(i), unique=TRUE))

})
```

Comment: setattr(h,"class","data.frame") should be instant, no copy at all.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- As is `setattr(h, "class", "data.table")` ;)  (Very cool, BTW).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Indeed :) Only realised in the last few days that `?setattr` says that `x` must be `data.table` (thanks to comment on datatable-help). `setattr` is actually intended to work on anything. Will fix docu. It returns its input too, so you can compound `[i,j,by]` afterwards if needed (say if you wrap it up into an alias: `setDT(DF)[i,j,by]`).

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Yeah, I tried your code and was pleased to see that it accomplished the conversion to `data.frame` without making any copies. Nice hacking!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien `setattr` is actually just a one line wrapper for R's C level `setAttrib` API function. Package `bit` has the same function, btw. It has `vecseq` too (I've just seen) which looks very handy. Might be worth reviewing `bit` to see what other gems it has (note to self).