# safest way to assign an integer (worried about truncation)

Tags: r, floating-point

I really just want to do something like

```
x <- as.integer(c(1,2,3))
```

But because c(1,2,3) is stored as a floating point vector I'm worried that I'll have problems with truncation, such as

```
> as.integer(1.99999999999)
[1] 1
```

How do I know I'm safe?

Comment: I worry sometimes too.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6155643/210673

Comment: @Aaron great thanks! And thanks for the spelling correction. I truncated truncation :)

Comment: Glad you found the link helpful, though the spelling correction was @Tomas.

Comment: @Aaron ah, then thanks to you and Tomas as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use a suffix `L`:

```
> x <- c(1L, 2L, 3L)
> is.integer(x)
[1] TRUE

> x <- 1L:3L
> x
[1] 1 2 3
> is.integer(x)
[1] TRUE
```

Or if you already have a numeric vector and convert it into integer, you can explicitly describe the rule:

```
> x <- c(-0.01, 1.999, 2, 3.000001)
> as.integer(round(x))
[1] 0 2 2 3
> as.integer(floor(x))
[1] -1  1  2  3
> as.integer(trunc(x))
[1] 0 1 2 3
> as.integer(ceiling(x))
[1] 0 2 2 4
```

Comment: As you show, `round` and company return floating point numbers so need to be coerced to integer.  Is there any need to worry about that coercion doing something unexpected?

Comment: What kind of unexpected behavior you think of?

Comment: Same as above, truncation.  Could the result from `round` and the others ever be stored as 1.999999999 (or the binary equivalent) so `as.integer` would return 1 instead of 2?

Comment: you can find the implementations here: http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/fround.c http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/arithmetic.c I think you don't need to worry about that.