# Most efficient list to data.frame method, when the list is a list of rows

Tags: r, memory-management, data-management

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942760/most-efficient-list-to-data-frame-method) covers the case where I have a list of columns, and I wish to turn them into a data.frame.  What if I have a list of rows, and I wish to turn them into a data.frame?

```
rowList <- lapply(1:500000,function(x) sample(0:1,300,x))
```

The naive way to solve this is using `rbind` and `as.data.frame`, but we can't even get past  the `rbind` step:

```
>Data <- do.call(rbind,vectorList)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 572.2 Mb
```

What is a more efficient to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient list to data.frame method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942760/most-efficient-list-to-data-frame-method)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich -- Are you sure it's a duplicate?  Zach is asking about `rbind`ing a bunch of vectors together. The methods examined in your linked post seem to all construct data.frames by `cbind`ing or otherwise combining columns.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: good point.  Zach needs to clarify, especially since `do.call(rbind, vectorList)` would create a matrix, not a data.frame.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: I edited my post.  Please let me know if it needs further clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would probably be fastest / most efficient to `unlist` your list and fill a matrix:

```
> m <- matrix(unlist(vectorList), ncol=300, nrow=length(vectorList), byrow=TRUE)
```

But you're going to need ~6GB of RAM to do that with integer vectors and ~12GB of RAM to do it with numeric vectors.

```
> l <- integer(5e6*300)
> print(object.size(l),units="Gb")
5.6 Gb
```

Answer (score 1):

Try direct coercion to matrix, by relying on the column major aspect of R arrays:

```
Data <- matrix(unlist(vectorList), ncol = length(vectorList[[1]]), byrow = TRUE)
```

If that also does not work you do not have the resources to copy this thing, so consider creating the matrix first and populating it column by column.