# How to most efficiently convert list of rows to a data frame in R

Tags: r, matrix

To be more specific, I have a list whose elements are vectors which correspond to one row of a data frame.

The method outline here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12382764/2472107

is extremely efficient/fast but it only works for lists that contain vectors that correspond to columns in a data frame.

I tried transposing the data frame afterwards, but this takes exceedingly long.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at `rbindlist` in package data.table. It's very fast. The result will be a data.table, which allows you to enjoy other advantages of that package. However, data.tables are also of class data.frame.

Comment: @Roland this suffers the same memory issue for me unfortunately. I suppose it may not be possible to set attributes of the lists of rows

Comment: @anon.mouse A data.frame is actually a list of vectors (with some additional restrictions) in R. The vectors are the columns of the data.frame. Thus, if you want your vectors to correspond to rows, it cannot be sufficient to merely set an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

From the context I gather that your elements are identical, say they are all `doubles`. If you want to transpose the data, it is much more efficient to put them in a `matrix`. You can do this with `matrix(unlist(x), ncol=length(x))`, where `x` is your list.

The code above also does the transpose. If you want to keep it as is you could say `matrix(unlist(x), nrow=length(x), byrow=TRUE)`.

Comment: I have already tried the 'matrix(unlist(x), ncol=length(x))' method and it is exceedingly slow and memory intensive as well. I suspect the most efficient method will involve only a change of the attributes of my list. Anything else is far too memory intensive

Comment: Transposing a `data.frame` is inherently slow because columns do not have the same type (among others). I think we have the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. What do you want to do exactly?