# Create a list from the last elements in vectors in a list

Tags: r, list, vector, dataframe

Suppose I have a `list` of vectors (none of them is empty; they may be of various lengths).

How can I generate a list of elements from the ends (say) of the vectors?

For example, if my list contains 3 elements, `1:10`, `2:9` and `c(3,5)`, then the output list should be the list containing `10`, `9` and `5`.

In the simpler case, where all vectors are of the same length (5, say), I tried to first make the list a `data.frame` using `as.data.frame`. The problem is that my list is **huge** (about 1 million vectors), and `as.data.frame` takes ages. I thought about optimization, perhaps using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943066/1565828), but anyway I think that it results a wrong data structure - instead of having 5 columns with 1 million values each, it creates a `data.frame` with a million columns.

So I should probably look somewhere else. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `x` is a list of atomic vectors, apply:

```
 sapply(x, function(elem) elem[length(elem)])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `tail`:

```
> sapply(list(1:10,2:9,c(3,5)),tail,1)
[1] 10  9  5
```

And @Bach is correct about speed. While `tail` is terse, it is slow:

```
set.seed(1)
a <- list()
for(i in 1:1e3)
    a[[i]] <- sample(1:100, sample(1:100), TRUE)

library("microbenchmark")
microbenchmark(sapply(a,tail,1), sapply(a, function(elem) elem[length(elem)]))
# Unit: milliseconds
#                                          expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#                            sapply(a, tail, 1) 22.998933 24.790584 26.103241 27.797130 79.489209   100
#  sapply(a, function(elem) elem[length(elem)])  1.546477  1.787224  1.951572  2.137856  6.106236   100
```

Comment: I think that @gagolews's solution is by far faster (not sure, though).

Comment: If speed is a concern neither solution should use `sapply`. Instead, `vapply` with an expected `numeric(1)`.

Comment: @flodel Good point. What do you have in mind instead of `sapply`? There is a gain from doing `unlist(lapply(...))` here, but are you thinking something else?