# Converting given list into dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following list:

```
$id1
$id1[[1]]
         A              B               
        "A"            "B"                
$id1[[2]]
         A             B 
        "A"           "A1" 
$id2
$id2[[1]]
         A              B               
        "A2"           "B2"
```

In R-pastable form:

```
dat = structure(list(SampleTable = structure(list(id2 = list(structure(c("90", "7"), .Names = c("T", "G")), structure(c("90", "8"), .Names = c("T", "G"))), id1 = structure(c("1", "1"), .Names = c("T", "G"))), .Names = c("id2", "id1"))), .Names = "SampleTable")
```

I want this given list to be converted into following dataframe:

```
id1   A    B
id1   A    A1 
id2   A2   B2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame duplicate?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra yeah, I think it should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Hmm, not entirely, the data structure is a bit different than in the duplicate I mentioned.

Comment: You're right, another lapply is needed. I take back my statement about closing. Vince's answer is spot on, too.

Comment: I have an additional answer using melt and cast which works on vincent's answer. I'm trying to undelete my previous answer. In short, this works 'cast(melt(d))[-1]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit messier that you let on. That `dat` object has an extra "layer" above it, so it is easier to work with `dat[[1]]`:

```
dfrm <- data.frame(dat[[1]], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(dfrm) <- sub("\\..+$", "", names(dfrm))

> dfrm
  id2 id2 id1
T  90  90   1
G   7   8   1
> t(dfrm)
    T    G  
id2 "90" "7"
id2 "90" "8"
id1 "1"  "1"
```

Answer (score 5):

Your data structure (apparently a named list of unnamed lists of 1-row data.frames) is a bit complicated: the easiest may be to use a loop to build the data.frame.

It can be done directly with `do.call`, `lapply` and `rbind`, but it is not very readable, even if you are familiar with those functions.

```
# Sample data 
d <- list(
  id1 = list(
    data.frame( x=1, y=1 ),
    data.frame( x=2, y=2 )
  ),
  id2 = list(
    data.frame( x=3, y=3 ),
    data.frame( x=4, y=4 )
  ),
  id3 = list(
    data.frame( x=5, y=5 ),
    data.frame( x=6, y=6 )
  )
)

# Convert
d <- data.frame(
  id=rep(names(d), unlist(lapply(d,length))),
  do.call( rbind, lapply(d, function(u) do.call(rbind, u)) )
)
```

Other solution, using a loop, if you have a ragged data structure, containing vectors (not data.frames) as explained in the comments.

```
d <- structure(list(SampleTable = structure(list(id2 = list(structure(c("90", "7"), .Names = c("T", "G")), structure(c("90", "8"), .Names = c("T", "G"))), id1 = structure(c("1", "1"), .Names = c("T", "G"))), .Names = c("id2", "id1"))), .Names = "SampleTable") 
result <- list()
for(i in seq_along(d$SampleTable)) {
  id <- names(d$SampleTable)[i]
  block <- d$SampleTable[[i]]
  if(is.atomic(block)) {
    block <- list(block)
  }
  for(row in block) {
    result <- c(result, list(data.frame(id, as.data.frame(t(row)))))
  }    
}
result <- do.call(rbind, result)
```

Comment: @Sjan if you think this answer solved your problem, feel free to check the grey mark below the answer score.

Comment: still the problem is not solved. problem comes when list contains a list element in it.

Comment: @Sjan: can you provide a reproducible example, e.g., the result of dput() on your data structure?

Comment: structure(list(SampleTable = structure(list(id2 = list(structure(c("90", 
"7"), .Names = c("T", "G")), structure(c("90", "8"), .Names = c("T", 
"G"))), id1 = structure(c("1", "1"), .Names = c("T", "G"))), .Names = c("id2", 
"id1"))), .Names = "SampleTable")

Comment: It would be better to add this to your question.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE! I could not get melt and cast working on this kind of ragged data (I tried for over an hour...) I am going to leave this answer here to show that for this kind of operation, the reshape pacakge could also be used.

Using the example data of vincent, you can use melt and cast from the reshape package:

```
library(reshape)
res = cast(melt(d))[-1]
names(res) = c("id","x","y")
res
   id x y
1 id1 1 1
2 id2 3 3
3 id3 5 5
4 id1 2 2
5 id2 4 4
6 id3 6 6
```

The order in the resulting data.frame is not the same, but the result is identical. And the code is a bit shorter. I use the `[-1]` to delete the first column which is also returned by `melt`. This additional variable is the column index of the individual data.frames in the list of lists. Just have a look at the result of `melt(d)`, that will hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: Could you mark it as the correct answer then? It is the grey tick mark on the left hand side of my answer, just beneath the up and down arrow and the 0. This let's people know that your question is answered, and gets met some rep ;).

Comment: Or mark the other answer as the corrct one if that was more helpful.

Comment: after runnning res = cast(melt(d))[-1] i got this message Error: Casting formula contains variables not found in molten data: variable

Comment: As I said in my note above, I could not get this working with your data, only with vincent's first example.