# Convert Triple Level List Structure into data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, nested-lists

I have a triple level list, the dput is below.  How can I convert this into a data.frame?  Output should be a 6x23 data.frame and preferably with the correct column names.  The number of rows is the `length()` of the top level list and the number of columns is combined `length()` of the lower-most level lists.

I tried doing this as suggested here ([R list to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame)):

`df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(l), nrow=6, byrow=T))`

and it almost works, but everything is converted to a factor.  This is because `unlist()` only returns a vector and everything is forced into the same data type.

Thank you.

```
list(structure(list(contract = structure(list(conId = "98333158", 
    symbol = "6823", sectype = "STK", exch = "SEHK", primary = "SEHK", 
    expiry = "", strike = "0", currency = "HKD", right = "0", 
    local = "6823", multiplier = "", combo_legs_desc = "", comboleg = "", 
    include_expired = "", secIdType = "", secId = ""), .Names = c("conId", 
"symbol", "sectype", "exch", "primary", "expiry", "strike", "currency", 
"right", "local", "multiplier", "combo_legs_desc", "comboleg", 
"include_expired", "secIdType", "secId"), class = "twsContract"), 
    portfolioValue = structure(list(position = 9000, marketPrice = 7.4949999, 
        marketValue = 67455, averageCost = 7.34352835, unrealizedPNL = 1363.24, 
        realizedPNL = 0, accountName = "U"), .Names = c("position", 
    "marketPrice", "marketValue", "averageCost", "unrealizedPNL", 
    "realizedPNL", "accountName"))), .Names = c("contract", "portfolioValue"
), class = "eventPortfolioValue"), structure(list(contract = structure(list(
    conId = "107651219", symbol = "EEM", sectype = "OPT", exch = "AMEX", 
    primary = "AMEX", expiry = "20130621", strike = "45", currency = "USD", 
    right = "C", local = "EEM   130622C00045000", multiplier = "100", 
    combo_legs_desc = "", comboleg = "", include_expired = "", 
    secIdType = "", secId = ""), .Names = c("conId", "symbol", 
"sectype", "exch", "primary", "expiry", "strike", "currency", 
"right", "local", "multiplier", "combo_legs_desc", "comboleg", 
"include_expired", "secIdType", "secId"), class = "twsContract"), 
    portfolioValue = structure(list(position = 7, marketPrice = 0.335, 
        marketValue = 234.5, averageCost = 191.78912855, unrealizedPNL = -1108.02, 
        realizedPNL = 0, accountName = "U"), .Names = c("position", 
    "marketPrice", "marketValue", "averageCost", "unrealizedPNL", 
    "realizedPNL", "accountName"))), .Names = c("contract", "portfolioValue"
), class = "eventPortfolioValue"), structure(list(contract = structure(list(
    conId = "114533598", symbol = "ESTX50", sectype = "FUT", 
    exch = "DTB", primary = "DTB", expiry = "20130621", strike = "0", 
    currency = "EUR", right = "0", local = "FESX JUN 13", multiplier = "10", 
    combo_legs_desc = "", comboleg = "", include_expired = "", 
    secIdType = "", secId = ""), .Names = c("conId", "symbol", 
"sectype", "exch", "primary", "expiry", "strike", "currency", 
"right", "local", "multiplier", "combo_legs_desc", "comboleg", 
"include_expired", "secIdType", "secId"), class = "twsContract"), 
    portfolioValue = structure(list(position = 0, marketPrice = 2639.5, 
        marketValue = 0, averageCost = 0, unrealizedPNL = 0, 
        realizedPNL = -84, accountName = "U"), .Names = c("position", 
    "marketPrice", "marketValue", "averageCost", "unrealizedPNL", 
    "realizedPNL", "accountName"))), .Names = c("contract", "portfolioValue"
), class = "eventPortfolioValue"), structure(list(contract = structure(list(
    conId = "44053851", symbol = "REM", sectype = "STK", exch = "ARCA", 
    primary = "ARCA", expiry = "", strike = "0", currency = "USD", 
    right = "0", local = "REM", multiplier = "", combo_legs_desc = "", 
    comboleg = "", include_expired = "", secIdType = "", secId = ""), .Names = c("conId", 
"symbol", "sectype", "exch", "primary", "expiry", "strike", "currency", 
"right", "local", "multiplier", "combo_legs_desc", "comboleg", 
"include_expired", "secIdType", "secId"), class = "twsContract"), 
    portfolioValue = structure(list(position = 200, marketPrice = 15.5649996, 
        marketValue = 3113, averageCost = 13.9649, unrealizedPNL = 320.02, 
        realizedPNL = 0, accountName = "U"), .Names = c("position", 
    "marketPrice", "marketValue", "averageCost", "unrealizedPNL", 
    "realizedPNL", "accountName"))), .Names = c("contract", "portfolioValue"
), class = "eventPortfolioValue"), structure(list(contract = structure(list(
    conId = "15016062", symbol = "USD", sectype = "CASH", exch = "IDEALPRO", 
    primary = "IDEALPRO", expiry = "", strike = "0", currency = "CAD", 
    right = "0", local = "USD.CAD", multiplier = "", combo_legs_desc = "", 
    comboleg = "", include_expired = "", secIdType = "", secId = ""), .Names = c("conId", 
"symbol", "sectype", "exch", "primary", "expiry", "strike", "currency", 
"right", "local", "multiplier", "combo_legs_desc", "comboleg", 
"include_expired", "secIdType", "secId"), class = "twsContract"), 
    portfolioValue = structure(list(position = 30000, marketPrice = 1.02540505, 
        marketValue = 30762.15, averageCost = 1.02867, unrealizedPNL = -97.95, 
        realizedPNL = 0, accountName = "U"), .Names = c("position", 
    "marketPrice", "marketValue", "averageCost", "unrealizedPNL", 
    "realizedPNL", "accountName"))), .Names = c("contract", "portfolioValue"
), class = "eventPortfolioValue"), structure(list(contract = structure(list(
    conId = "37928772", symbol = "USD", sectype = "CASH", exch = "IDEALPRO", 
    primary = "IDEALPRO", expiry = "", strike = "0", currency = "SGD", 
    right = "0", local = "USD.SGD", multiplier = "", combo_legs_desc = "", 
    comboleg = "", include_expired = "", secIdType = "", secId = ""), .Names = c("conId", 
"symbol", "sectype", "exch", "primary", "expiry", "strike", "currency", 
"right", "local", "multiplier", "combo_legs_desc", "comboleg", 
"include_expired", "secIdType", "secId"), class = "twsContract"), 
    portfolioValue = structure(list(position = 75000, marketPrice = 1.25079, 
        marketValue = 93809.25, averageCost = 1.2473, unrealizedPNL = 261.75, 
        realizedPNL = 0, accountName = "U"), .Names = c("position", 
    "marketPrice", "marketValue", "averageCost", "unrealizedPNL", 
    "realizedPNL", "accountName"))), .Names = c("contract", "portfolioValue"
), class = "eventPortfolioValue"))
```

Comment: Dint notice that in your answer. deleted mine. Will repost if I could think of something better.

Comment: The matrix call will coerce to a common mode, "character", and then the data.frame call will coerce to factor unless stringsAsFactors is set to FALSE.

Comment: @Dwin Thanks - settings stringsAsFactors creates a data.frame with everything as a "char" as you mentioned.  Can I do this operation without using `unlist` and `matrix`? These are the two operations causing me issues by coercing everything into a common mode.

Comment: @mchangun looks like you are using `IBrokers` to get your account informations.. try this function `twsPortfolioValue`

Comment: @geektrader That is indeed what I am doing.  How does `twsPortfolio` work? Doing `twsPortfolioValue(tws)` gives me an error `Error in UseMethod("twsPortfolioValue") : 
  no applicable method for 'twsPortfolioValue' applied to an object of class "c('twsconn', 'environment')"`

Comment: try `twsPortfolioValue(reqAccountUpdates(tws), zero.pos=TRUE, ...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `lapply` though each sub-list calling `as.data.frame.list` explicitly. Then piece together with `rbind`.

```
dfr <- do.call(rbind,lapply(l,function(x) as.data.frame.list(lapply(x,as.data.frame.list))))
dim(dfr)
[1]  6 23
table(sapply(dfr,class))

 factor numeric 
     17       6
```

Comment: if OP doesn't want characters to be converted to factors then perhaps you should add `dfr <- do.call(rbind,lapply(l,function(x) as.data.frame.list(lapply(x,as.data.frame.list,stringsAsFactors=FALSE))))`