# convert triple nested list to dataframe

Tags: r, nested-lists, ibrokers

I'm trying to convert a triple nested list into a dataframe. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527053/convert-triple-level-list-structure-into-data-frame) question has helped, but I can't get the dataframe I'd like.

The list is an options chain obtained from IBrokers, a summary is shown below. I've uploaded the actual chain [here](https://github.com/hughandersen/OptionsTrading/blob/master/Stocks_option_chain) which is more detailed.

```
Chain <- 
  list(
    list(
      list(
        list(version="8",contract=list(symbol="BHP",right="C",expiry="20180621",strike="25")),
        list(version="8",contract=list(symbol="BHP",right="C",expiry="20180621",strike="26"))
      ),
      list(
        list(version="8",contract=list(symbol="BHP",right="C",expiry="20180730",strike="25")),
        list(version="8",contract=list(symbol="BHP",right="C",expiry="20180730",strike="26"))
      )
    ),
    list(
      list(
        list(version="8",contract=list(symbol="CBA",right="C",expiry="20180621",strike="65")),
        list(version="8",contract=list(symbol="CBA",right="C",expiry="20180621",strike="64"))
      ),
      list(
        list(version="8",contract=list(symbol="CBA",right="C",expiry="20180730",strike="65")),
        list(version="8",contract=list(symbol="CBA",right="C",expiry="20180730",strike="64"))
      )
    )
  )
```

I'd like to convert the list into a dataframe like this:

```
Contracts <- data.frame(symbol=c("BHP","BHP","BHP","BHP","CBA","CBA","CBA","CBA"),
                        right=c("C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C"),
                        expiry=c("20180621","20180621","20180730","20180730","20180621","20180621","20180730","20180730"),
                        strike=c("25","26","25","26","65","64","65","64"))
```

I tried this code, but it didn't give me the dataframe I wanted.

```
X <- lapply(Chain,function(x) as.data.frame.list(lapply(x,as.data.frame.list)))
dfx <- do.call(rbind,X)
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unstack`

```
 unstack(data.frame(d<-unlist(Chain),names(d)))
  contract.expiry contract.right contract.strike contract.symbol version
1        20180621              C              25             BHP       8
2        20180621              C              26             BHP       8
3        20180730              C              25             BHP       8
4        20180730              C              26             BHP       8
5        20180621              C              65             CBA       8
6        20180621              C              64             CBA       8
7        20180730              C              65             CBA       8
8        20180730              C              64             CBA       8
```

If you want you can delete the word `contract`.

```
unstack(data.frame(d<-unlist(Chain),sub(".*[.]","",names(d))))
    expiry right strike symbol version
1 20180621     C     25    BHP       8
2 20180621     C     26    BHP       8
3 20180730     C     25    BHP       8
4 20180730     C     26    BHP       8
5 20180621     C     65    CBA       8
6 20180621     C     64    CBA       8
7 20180730     C     65    CBA       8
8 20180730     C     64    CBA       8
```

This can also be written as `unstack(data.frame(d<-unlist(Chain),sub("contract[.]","",names(d))))` Although I would prefer to maintain the name contract in order to know which columns indeed form the contract dataframe needed

Or even you can change the names After `unstacking`.

With the new data:

```
a=readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hughandersen/OptionsTrading/master/Stocks_option_chain")
b=eval(parse(text=paste(a,collapse="")))
s=unstack(data.frame(d<-unlist(b[6]),names(d)))
```

Comment: The answer doesn't work on the actual options chain - I'll try and link the actual chain output as a dput to the question, I think the dummy list is too simplified

Comment: really? huh.. maybe try to use `recursive=T` inside the `unlist`.. i cant tell as to why

Comment: I've uploaded the actual chain to the question - let me know if you have problems downloading it

Comment: thanks for your help, this works with the full listed option chain. I've never heard of ``unstack``.

Comment: Well hope you are using `Rgui` and not `Rstudio` since the file is just enormous. I guess more than 25MB

Comment: you're right, its just over 25mB, I'm using RStudio with lots of RAM

Comment: @Onyambu I have a small question here, how to keep the initial column class after changing the list to a data frame. I used this syntax in my data, but all the columns have been changed from chron/number to character. I want to keep the initial column class.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following?

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(Chain, recursive = T), ncol = 5, byrow = T)[, -1]);
colnames(df) <- c("symbol", "right", "expiry", "strike");
#  symbol right   expiry strike
#1    BHP     C 20180621     25
#2    BHP     C 20180621     26
#3    BHP     C 20180730     25
#4    BHP     C 20180730     26
#5    CBA     C 20180621     65
#6    CBA     C 20180621     64
#7    CBA     C 20180730     65
#8    CBA     C 20180730     64
```

Explanation: Recursively `unlist` the nested `Chain`, then recast as `matrix`, remove column `version` and convert to `data.frame`. The only minor down-side is that we have to manually add column names.

---

### Update

Since your actual data is quite different, here is a possibility.
**Note: I assume the structure from the Gist is stored in `tbl`**.

```
tbl;
#Source: local data frame [2 x 6]
#Groups: <by row>
#
## A tibble: 2 x 6
#  symbol sectype exch  currency multiplier Chain
#  <fct>  <fct>   <fct> <fct>    <fct>      <list>
#1 BHP    OPT     ASX   AUD      100        <list [1,241]>
#2 CBA    OPT     ASX   AUD      100        <list [1,204]>
```

The following `list` contains two `data.frame`s, one for each row from `tbl`.

```
lst <- lapply(tbl$Chain, function(x)
    do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(x, function(y) as.data.frame(unclass(y$contract)))))
#List of 2
# $ :'data.frame':  1241 obs. of  16 variables:
#  ..$ conId          : Factor w/ 1241 levels "198440202","198440207",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  ..$ symbol         : Factor w/ 1 level "BHP": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ sectype        : Factor w/ 1 level "OPT": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ exch           : Factor w/ 1 level "ASX": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ primary        : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ expiry         : Factor w/ 18 levels "20180628","20181220",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ strike         : Factor w/ 118 levels "25","26","27",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
#  ..$ currency       : Factor w/ 1 level "AUD": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ right          : Factor w/ 2 levels "C","P": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
#  ..$ local          : Factor w/ 1241 levels "BHPV78","BHPV88",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  ..$ multiplier     : Factor w/ 1 level "100": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ combo_legs_desc: Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ comboleg       : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ include_expired: Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ secIdType      : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ secId          : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ :'data.frame':  1204 obs. of  16 variables:
#  ..$ conId          : Factor w/ 1204 levels "198447027","198447030",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  ..$ symbol         : Factor w/ 1 level "CBA": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ sectype        : Factor w/ 1 level "OPT": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ exch           : Factor w/ 1 level "ASX": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ primary        : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ expiry         : Factor w/ 18 levels "20180628","20181220",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ strike         : Factor w/ 179 levels "79.68","81.68",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
#  ..$ currency       : Factor w/ 1 level "AUD": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ right          : Factor w/ 2 levels "C","P": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
#  ..$ local          : Factor w/ 1204 levels "CBAKT9","CBAKU9",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  ..$ multiplier     : Factor w/ 1 level "100": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ combo_legs_desc: Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ comboleg       : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ include_expired: Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ secIdType      : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ secId          : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works for an uneven list. Adding column names isn't a problem.

Comment: I can't get your answer to work on the actual chain which I've uploaded to the question. Can you try again with the actual chain?

Comment: @Zeus Your actual chain has a *very different* structure from your sample data. Obviously my solution will not work, as it is based on the keys from your sample data. TBH, your chain data is **very unwieldy** (it's a large, complex & nested `list` with keys that are *not consistent* between entries), and I'm not even sure which entries you want to extract. Is it possible to extract the relevant bits directly when scraping the data?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I should have uploaded the list in the first place. Unfortunately I cannot control how the data is returned from the broker. I don't want all the information, just the data in the lists ``.. .. ..$contract``

Comment: @Zeus But the data you provide seems to be a 2-row `tibble` with a nested `list` in column `Chain`. Is that afore-mentioned `Chain` from which you want to extract `.. .. ..$contract`? Since you have two rows, you also have two nested lists. Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170053/discussion-between-zeus-and-maurits-evers).

Comment: Both methods work, @Onyambu and Maurits thanks for your help