# How to load a MATLAB struct into a R data frame?

Tags: r, matlab, dataframe, import, matlab-struct

I have a MATLAB struct, containing a number of fields which together describe, say, 100 observations of a number of variables, as follows (MATLAB output):

```
mystruct = 

  fieldA: [100x1 double]
  fieldB: [100x1 double]
  fieldC: [100x1 double]
  fieldD: [100x1 char]
  fieldE: {100x1 cell}
```

I want to use R with this data, so I save the struct as a .mat file. and import it using the [R.matlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/index.html) package. Because I'm new to R, the following is likely clumsy, but I can access individual fields just fine (R code):

```
> f = readMat('myfile.mat')
> data = f$mystruct
> data
  , , 1

      [,1]         
  fieldA Numeric,100  
  fieldB Numeric,100  
  fieldC Numeric,100  
  fieldD Character,100
  fieldE List,100   

> data = data[, , 1]
> df <- data.frame(fieldA = data$fieldA, fieldB = data$fieldB)
```

OK, so here is the question: how can I generalize the above so that a data frame is generated for an arbitrary number of fields in the original struct? For my 5-field example I can manually do it, but the next data set I have has many fields, and I don't want to enter them all.

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame), I tried `rbind()` and `ldply()`, which construct outrageously dimensioned data frames (401 obs of 1 variable and 401 obs of 105 variables respectively).

Comment: It depends on what's in `data` (you could post the output of`str(data)`), but perhaps all you need is `df <- as.data.frame(data)`

Comment: summary of `data` now included; doing this gives a data frame with 100 obs of 104 variables (should be 100 obs of 5 variables)

Comment: I suspect FieldE is converted to 100 variables of length 1 instead of 1 variable of length 100. Does ` drop=c("singletonLists")` help?

Comment: As an alternative, if your structure object isn't too large, have `Matlab` write it to a csv file, read that in, and resize/reshape as desired.

Answer (score 7):

As it turns out, the MATLAB cell array (`fieldE`) was imported as a nested list. Using `unlist` takes care of the problem:

```
data = lapply(data, unlist, use.names=FALSE)
df <- as.data.frame(data) # now has correct number of obs and vars
```

Thanks @koekenbakker for the critical pointer to this!