# Creating data frame of MATLAB data in R

Tags: r, matlab, dataframe

I have been given a MATLAB data set with 20 different variables. I've been able to read it into R using readMat().
When I look at the structure (str()) I get the following output, and I'm wanting to create a data frame so I can run further analysis.
[structure output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw01u.jpg)

I've tried using data.frame() but this only gives me 1 variable with 2 observations.

I've also tried lapply() but it gives many observations with only 1 variable.
[r code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go049.jpg)

How can I create a data frame that shows the correct variables and observations?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Hi Ronak Shah - I don't believe I'm allowed to share my data (agreements etc). Is there some other way? Apologies, this is my first question.

Comment: Have you tried df <- as.data.frame(df)

Comment: Yes, as.data.frame() gives me the same object

Comment: According to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28097519/6288065), I think you're supposed to use lapply() not on dat, but on the structure inside dat, which is dat$SG_surveys_stn_p_scalar_data.mat, like `lapply(dat$SG_surveys_stn_p_scalar_data.mat, unlist, use.names=FALSE)`.

Comment: Thanks @LC-datascientist, I've tried the new lapply like you've written and get an object of a large list with 2 elements. Very similar to my first problem unfortunately.

Comment: from the image ot would look like `as.data.frame(dat[[1]][[1]])` would work, and then grab the names from the second entry perhaps with `c(unlist(dat[[1]][[2]]))` or similar

Comment: @user20650 This worked! Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

From the image you attached it looks like you could try `data.frame(dat[[1]][[1]])` for the data.

The column names appear to be nested under `dat[[1]][[2]]` so you might need to use `lapply` or `flatten (dat[[1]][[2]])`.