# R list of lists to data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a list of lists, call it `listHolder`, which has length 5.

Every element in `listHolder` is a list of numeric data, with 160 or so elements.

I need to turn this list of lists into a `data.frame` of length 5, with each element being a numeric vector with 160 or so elements.

But everything I've tried, from iterating through the list of lists and turning each element with `as.numeric(unlist(listHolder[[i]]))`, to

```
data.frame(matrix(unlist(listHolder), nrow = length(totalKeywords), byrow = T))
```

ends up creating a data frame of length 160 or so, with each element being a numeric vector with 5 or so elements.

How do I do what I want?

Attempting `data.frame(matrix(unlist(totalKeywords), nrow=132, byrow=T))` yields the opposite of what I want - 160 small items each 5 elements long.

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, listHolder)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R list to data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame)

Comment: I think he wants to turn each listHolder item in a column, so it would be `cbind` instead of `rbind`.

Comment: Why not `as.data.frame(listHolder)`

Comment: Could you provide sample data for `listHolder`?

Comment: Sure: print(listHolder) = [[1]] [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1... (on for 160 or so), [[2]] [1] 4 0 2 4 23 0 3 2 4... (on for 160 or so), [[3]] [1] 2 3 1 3 3.... and so on. I tried the solution in "R list to data frame", and ended up with 160 objects called "X1" "X2" "X3" and so on, each of them with five members. doing do.call(cbind, listHolder) gives me what looks like a matrix - the columns labeled with [,1] [,2] [,3] and the rows with [1,], [2,], [3,] and so on

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The value of nrow needs to be fixed. I fixed your code as follows:

```
dd  <-  as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(listHolder), nrow=length(unlist(listHolder[1]))))
```

Comment: Is there anything I could do to preserve types? Following this approach, if one column was `POSIXct`, it converts it to `chr`.

Comment: Types can be preserved by using `Reduce` (as in my answer).

Answer (score 52):

AS @dimitris_ps mentioned earlier, the answer could be:

```
do.call(rbind, listHolder)
```

Since **do.call** naturally "strips" 1 level of the "list of list", obtaining a list, not a list of lists.

After that, **rbind** can handle the elements on the list and create a *matrix*.

Comment: This extremely useful when the "rows" were named lists, as it keeps the names of the list (assuming the names are consistent)

Comment: ...and it does not change data types like 'unlist' above. This is the Answer!

Comment: Super useful! However, is there a way to incude the number/name of each list into the final dataframe?

Answer (score 18):

This is the easiest solution I've found.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(data.table)

dt_list <- map(list_of_lists, as.data.table)
dt <- rbindlist(dt_list, fill = TRUE, idcol = T)

dt
```

Comment: The only way that worked for me. Still, does not preserve `POSIXct` as was asked earlier.

Comment: Do you really need the `library(jsonlite)`? You can replace that with `library(magrittr)` and have it in one go: `map(list_of_lists, as.data.table) %>% rbindlist(...)`

Answer (score 13):

I keep coming to this question and usually end up adapting the current answers to my need.

Current answers either mess up with types of variables, or do not handle well proper **list of lists** (note the plural).

#### tl;dr: use the following:

This works when each element in listHolder contains a column of the dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(listHolder, function(x) Reduce(c, x)))
```

This works when each element in listHolder contains a row of the dataframe

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(listHolder, data.frame))
```

#### Minimal Working Example (list elements are columns)

The following code provides a MWE and reviews other answers. The `#General Approach` is what I would recommend to use.

```
listHolder <- list(
  A = rep(list(1, 2), 80),
  B = rep(c(3, 4), 80),
  C = rep(c("a", "b"), 80),
  D = rep(list("c", "d"), 80),
  E = rep(as.POSIXct(10485849600, origin = "1582-10-14", tz = "GMT"), 160)
)


# @Noha's Answer
data1  <-  as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(listHolder), nrow=length(unlist(listHolder[1]))))
# Try this (mess up with types)
str(data1)

# @Camilo's Answer
data2 <- data.frame(do.call(cbind, listHolder))
# Try this (each column becomes a list)
str(data2)

# General Approach
data3 <- data.frame(lapply(listHolder, function(x) Reduce(c, x)))
str(data3)
```

#### Minimal Working Example (list elements are rows)

This code should be used when each element in the list is supposed to hold a row in the dataframe

```
listHolder <- list(
  row1 = list(name = "foo", surname = "bar", age = 90),
  row2 = list(name = "foo", surname = "foo", age = 29),
  row3 = list(name = "bar", surname = "foo", age = 45),
  row4 = list(name = "bar", surname = "bar", age = 10)
)

# A simple rbind won't work (each column is still a list)
data1 <- do.call(rbind, listHolder)
str(data1)

# General Approach (now it's better)
data2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(listHolder, data.frame))
str(data2)
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. It is exactly what I am looking for but some of my data has a catch. There are NULL values for some elements in some lists. These values are ignored so the lists are of different lengths and it trips over. Do you have a solution that can handle this?

Comment: I guess you would need to clean the lists first. For example you can try this: `listHolder <- lapply(listHolder, function(x) { Map(function(z){ifelse(is.null(z), NA, z)},  x) })`. This will replace all NULL values in your sublists with an NA. You can then replace this in your data.frame as you wish, or use other replacement values. This will not work however for vectors. I.e. if your main list contains vector of different lengths, you would need further cleaning (and I would probably go with a loop in this case).

Answer (score 11):

This achieves a similar result, but is more intuitive (to me at least)

```
#Generate fake data 
listoflists=list(c(1,'a',3,4),c(5,'b',6,7))

#Convert to a dataframe, transpose, and convert the resulting matrix back to a dataframe
df= as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(listoflists)))

#Strip out the rownames if desired
rownames(df)<-NULL

#Show result
df
```

Comment: This is not a list of lists. This is a list of atomic vector (coerced to character since you have different data types).

Answer (score -1):

I think this is easier than the previous solutions:

```
mydf = data.frame(x1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
mylist = list(c(4, 5), c(4, 5), c(4, 5))
mydf$x2 = mylist
print(mydf)
  x1   x2
1  a 4, 5
2  b 4, 5
3  c 4, 5
```

Comment: Also not a list a of lists