# Create dataframe from list of lists in R

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting

I have a variable `out` that is a list of lists and I want to format the first child list to a dataframe. Say my `out` looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$id
[1] "1"

[[1]]$input
[1] "A" "B" "C" 

[[2]]
[[2]]$id
[1] "2"

[[2]]$input
[1] "R" "S" "T"
```

`class(out)` and `class(out[[1]])` confirms that this is a list of lists.

I want to create a "long" dataframe that should look like this:

```
id    input
1     "A"
1     "B"
1     "C"
2     "R"
2     "S"
2     "T"
```

I tried:

```
lapply(out, function(x){
     as.data.frame(x)
   })
```

but this seems to do an `cbind` and creates new columns for each child list.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674661/r-list-of-lists-to-data-frame

Comment: I think you need `do.call(rbind,lapply(out, as.data.frame))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
library(plyr)
ldply(out, as.data.frame)
```