# List of sublists with different lengths and types to dataframe R

Tags: r

I have a list of lists `list_of_lists`.

Each sub_list can have a different length theoretically, like:

```
list_of_lists[[1]]
$id = 1
$variable1 = "8"
$variable2 = 8  12.2
```

and...

```
list_of_lists[[2]]
$id = 2
$variable1 = "4"
$variable2 = 2  2.2  12.1 200.1
```

I want to convert the `list_of_lists` to a long dataframe. Have looked at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674661/r-list-of-lists-to-data-frame):

```
b = as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(list_of_lists), nrow=length(unlist(list_of_lists[1]))))
```

and have tried this:

```
long_df = ldply(list_of_lists, as.data.frame)
```

Neither works as I expect it.

I want to have a long df like:

```
id    variable1    variable2
1     "8"          8
1     "8"          12.2
2     "4"          2
2     "4"          2.2
2     "4"          12.1
2     "4"          200.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert each sublist to a data frame individually and then `rbind` them assuming all sublists have same fields:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(list_of_lists, data.frame))

#   id var1  var2
# 1  1    8   8.0
# 2  1    8  12.2
# 3  2    4   2.0
# 4  2    4   2.2
# 5  2    4  12.1
# 6  2    4 200.1
```