# Add list of list into a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to add a list of list into a dataframe

```
list1<-list(1,2,3)
list2<-NA
list3<-list(1,2,3)

list<-list(list1,list2,list3)

Mydata<-data.frame(x=NA,y=NA)
```

Would like to produce

```
x  y  
NA list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1 row result

If you are looking to maintain a single row in `y` then try this:

```
Mydata$y <- list(list)
```

### 3 row result

If you are looking for a 3-row result try this.  The second line can be omitted if it is ok if `y` has `AsIs` class.

```
Mydata2 <- data.frame(Mydata[-2], y = I(list))
class(Mydata2$y) <- NULL
```

or

```
Mydata3 <-  replicate(length(list), Mydata)
Mydata3$y <- list
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below:

```
#Example list including other lists.
mainList = list(c(4,22,25,66),c(11,'77',2,5))

#convert list to dataframe, transpose and convert back to dataframe again
df= as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(mainList )))

#You can set NULL to row names if required.
rownames(df)<-NULL

#Show result
df
```

Online compiler: https://rextester.com/OIIQ72692

Reference: [R list of lists to data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674661/r-list-of-lists-to-data-frame)