# How to make a summary data.frame in R, with mixed data types

Tags: r, dataframe, summary

Fully aware that this *type* of question has been asked hundreds of times.
Still, I could not find an answer to the specific problem I am describing, which is about:

- performance (i.e. I know *how* to do what I need, but it's too slow in some cases, so I am looking for a faster solution)
- good programming practice (i.e. I am questioning whether the approach I chose is 'clean' rather than roundabout or inefficient for other reasons)

I have a data.frame with numerical and character columns. I need to create a data.frame summary from it, *grouping by one of the character columns (`ID`)*, and reporting 1) some stats about some numerical columns within each group, *and* 2) some character concatenations (i.e. the report has *mixed* data types - that's what makes it tricky, at least for me, and that's why I am asking for advice).

Here is the `R` script:

```
# Simulate original data.frame

set.seed(384092)

N <- 10000

d <- data.frame("ID" = paste0(sample(LETTERS, N, replace = T),  sprintf("%03.0f", sample(1:floor(sqrt(N)), N, replace = T )) ), stringsAsFactors = F)
d["set"] <- sample(LETTERS, N, replace = T)
d["P"] <- runif(N, -20, 120)
d["K"] <- rnorm(N, 10, 0.5)

# Make summary
# For each unique ID, report: ID, number of rows of d, mean of P, sd of P, comma-separated list of unique set's

# Method 1: rbind data.frames from 'by'

time.1 <- system.time({
  d_summary.1 <- do.call(rbind, by(d, d$ID, function(dd) {
    data.frame("ID" = dd$ID[1], "N" = nrow(dd), "P_mean" = mean(dd$P), "P_sd" = sd(dd$P), "sets" = paste(unique(dd$set), collapse = ","))
  })
  )
})

cat("\ntime.1 =",time.1,"\n")
print(sapply(d_summary.1, class))

# Method 2: create a list of lists and combine them at the end
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/68162050/6376297

time.2 <- system.time({
  time.2.1 <- system.time({d_summary.2 <- by(d, d$ID, function(dd) {
    list("ID" = dd$ID[1], "N" = nrow(dd), "P_mean" = mean(dd$P), "P_sd" = sd(dd$P), "sets" = paste(unique(dd$set), collapse = ","))
  })
  })
  d_summary.2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(d_summary.2, data.frame))
})

cat("\ntime.2.1 =",time.2.1)
cat("\ntime.2 =",time.2,"\n")
print(sapply(d_summary.2, class))
```

which on my PC produces the following output:

```
time.1 = 1.72 0 1.72 NA NA 
         ID           N      P_mean        P_sd        sets 
"character"   "integer"   "numeric"   "numeric" "character" 

time.2.1 = 0.3 0 0.29 NA NA
time.2 = 1.79 0 1.82 NA NA 
         ID           N      P_mean        P_sd        sets 
"character"   "integer"   "numeric"   "numeric" "character"
```

The linked post https://stackoverflow.com/a/68162050/6376297 specifically mentions that the kind of handling used in method 2 is necessary to avoid coercing all columns to a single data type.
And indeed, any solution I tried that relies on making an intermediate matrix, as fully expected, results in coercion to character.

This is really unfortunate, because as shown by `time.2.1`, the initial formation of a list of lists containing the required information (and still retaining all the original data types) takes only 1/6 - 1/5 of the total time.
And you need to imagine that I am doing this on `d`'s at least 10-100 times larger than this example.

> Would anyone be able to advise / suggest a faster method to do this?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT** : follow up from users' feedback

Trial of the `dplyr` (4) and `data.table` (5) method, plus a couple more base `R` methods (using `aggregate`, (6) and (7)) that are more involved but might be somewhat competitive with those two.

```
# Method 4: dplyr

require(dplyr)

time.4 <- system.time({
  d %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(N = n(),
              P_mean = mean(P),
              P_sd = sd(P),
              sets = paste(unique(set), collapse = ",")) -> d_summary.4
})

cat("\ntime.4 =",time.4,"\n")
print(sapply(d_summary.4, class))

# Method 5: data.table

require(data.table)

time.5 <- system.time({
  setDT(d)
  
  d_summary.5 <- d[, .(N = .N, 
        P_mean = mean(P), 
        P_sd = sd(P), 
        sets = toString(unique(set))), ID]
  
  d_summary.5 <- as.data.frame(d_summary.5)
  
})

cat("\ntime.5 =",time.5,"\n")
print(sapply(d_summary.5, class))

# Method 6: aggregate each column separately and merge

time.6 <- system.time({
  
  d_summary.6 <- setNames(as.data.frame(table(d$ID), stringsAsFactors = F),c("ID","N"))
  d_summary.6 <- merge(d_summary.6, setNames(aggregate(P ~ ID, data = d, FUN = mean),c("ID","P_mean")), by = "ID")
  d_summary.6 <- merge(d_summary.6, setNames(aggregate(P ~ ID, data = d, FUN = sd),c("ID","P_sd")), by = "ID")
  d_summary.6 <- merge(d_summary.6, setNames(aggregate(set ~ ID, data = d, FUN = function(x) {paste(unique(x),collapse=",")}),c("ID","sets")), by = "ID")
  
})

cat("\ntime.6 =",time.6,"\n")
print(sapply(d_summary.6, class))

# Method 7: aggregate each column separately and cbind (this assumes that both table and aggregate will report all values of ID, sorted)

time.7 <- system.time({
  
  d_summary.7 <- setNames(as.data.frame(table(d$ID), stringsAsFactors = F),c("ID","N"))
  d_summary.7 <- cbind(d_summary.7, "P_mean" = aggregate(P ~ ID, data = d, FUN = mean)[,2])
  d_summary.7 <- cbind(d_summary.7, "P_sd" = aggregate(P ~ ID, data = d, FUN = sd)[,2])
  d_summary.7 <- cbind(d_summary.7, "sets" = aggregate(set ~ ID, data = d, FUN = function(x) {paste(unique(x),collapse=",")})[,2])
  
})

cat("\ntime.7 =",time.7,"\n")
print(sapply(d_summary.7, class))
```

Timing:

```
time.1 = 1.73 0.02 1.77 NA NA 
         ID           N      P_mean        P_sd        sets 
"character"   "integer"   "numeric"   "numeric" "character" 

time.2.1 = 0.29 0 0.3 NA NA
time.2 = 1.83 0.01 1.84 NA NA 
         ID           N      P_mean        P_sd        sets 
"character"   "integer"   "numeric"   "numeric" "character" 

time.4 = 0.13 0 0.13 NA NA 
         ID           N      P_mean        P_sd        sets 
"character"   "integer"   "numeric"   "numeric" "character" 

time.5 = 0.08 0 0.08 NA NA 
         ID           N      P_mean        P_sd        sets 
"character"   "integer"   "numeric"   "numeric" "character" 

time.6 = 0.25 0 0.25 NA NA 
         ID           N      P_mean        P_sd        sets 
"character"   "integer"   "numeric"   "numeric" "character" 

time.7 = 0.25 0 0.25 NA NA 
         ID           N      P_mean        P_sd        sets 
"character"   "integer"   "numeric"   "numeric" "character"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `dplyr` for this task:

```r
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(N = n(),
            P_mean = mean(P),
            P_sd = sd(P),
            sets = paste(unique(set), collapse = ","))
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 2,553 x 5
   ID        N P_mean  P_sd sets     
   <chr> <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
 1 A001      4   27.4  42.1 N,Z,C    
 2 A002      3   46.6  40.6 Z,R,L    
 3 A003      5   31.8  28.0 S,F,X,H,U
 4 A004      5   46.4  36.0 H,W,U,P,R
 5 A005      3   53.6  24.7 I,Y,B    
 6 A006      2   58.9  61.9 V,J      
 7 A007      5   68.2  53.8 Y,X,W,N,F
 8 A008      4   64.5  14.0 X,I,V,D  
 9 A009      1   61.4  NA   L        
10 A010      2   95.5  30.0 S,L      
# ... with 2,543 more rows
```

Compared (on my machine) to your other methods:

```r
time.1 = 1.02 0 1.02 NA NA 

time.2.1 = 0.17 0 0.17 NA NA

time.2 = 1.11 0 1.11 NA NA 

# dplyr-method
time.3 = 0.07 0 0.08 NA NA 
         ID           N      P_mean        P_sd        sets 
"character"   "integer"   "numeric"   "numeric" "character"
```

Comment: Thanks! Your method is 15-20 times faster than mine on the N = 10000 case. I usually refrain from using non-base R, but dplyr is a very popular package, so I might have to give in. I will post an update.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `data.table` approach -

```
library(data.table)

setDT(d)

d[, .(N = .N, 
      P_mean = mean(P), 
      P_sd = sd(P), 
      sets = toString(unique(set))), ID]

#        ID N P_mean P_sd             sets
#   1: M074 6  66.30 32.1 I, O, K, S, W, Y
#   2: E016 4  60.23 25.3       E, Y, I, L
#   3: W043 3  46.62 46.2          Q, U, L
#   4: Y059 5  93.59 26.8    G, T, L, O, S
#   5: R073 7  61.16 44.1    N, P, M, I, S
#  ---                                    
#2549: B012 2   6.68 27.7             Z, G
#2550: H088 1  -4.08   NA                X
#2551: T052 1  27.65   NA                E
#2552: C087 1  74.33   NA                M
#2553: Q021 1  30.29   NA                P
```

Comment: Thanks! Same as for the other answer, your method is 15-20 times faster than mine on the N = 10000 case. I thought I had read somewhere that data.table was now used for all standard data.frame R handling; apparently not. I will post an update with a trial of your method, too.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
fpaste <- function(x) toString(funique(x))
out <- collap(d, ~ ID, custom = list(fnobs = "set",
      fmean = "P", fsd = "P", fpaste = "set"))
```

-output

```
head(out)
    ID fnobs.set    fpaste.set  fmean.P    fsd.P
1 A001         4       N, Z, C 27.43196 42.10786
2 A002         3       Z, R, L 46.57773 40.55696
3 A003         5 S, F, X, H, U 31.84874 27.96048
4 A004         5 H, W, U, P, R 46.37885 36.03823
5 A005         3       I, Y, B 53.62615 24.67470
6 A006         2          V, J 58.91548 61.88600
```

#### Benchmarks

```
 N <- 1000000
system.time({
out <- collap(d, ~ ID, custom = list(fnobs = "set",
      fmean = "P", fsd = "P", fpaste = "set"))
})
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.513   0.015   0.526 

system.time({
setDT(d)

d[, .(N = .N, 
      P_mean = mean(P), 
      P_sd = sd(P), 
      sets = toString(unique(set))), ID]

}) 

# user  system elapsed 
#  0.646   0.015   0.659
```