# how to convert a "2D" vector into data frame/matrix? [R]

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, apply

Hi I apply a function to each column of a data frame, and for each column it returns a list. Now I wanna convert this list into a matrix or data frame.

Have read [this nice post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame) and still have some questions.

```
df = data.frame(name = c('Tom', 'Mark', 'Jane'),
            weight = c(150, 140, 110),
            sex = c('M', 'M', 'F'), 
            fulltime = c(T, T, F), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$sex = as.factor(df$sex)

# return a list
f1 = function(column){
        list( class = class(column),
              mean = mean(column)
        )
}
```

lapply + do.call(rbind) works:

```
result = lapply(df[,], f1)
result

test1 = do.call(rbind.data.frame, result)
test1

# this seems to be same
test2 = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, result), stringsAsFactors = T) 
test2
identical(test1, test2) # i don't know why not identical...
```

Why sapply doesn't work - it looks great at first:

```
result = sapply(df, f1)
result # looks perfect:
#        name        weight    sex      fulltime 
# class "character" "numeric" "factor" "logical"
# mean  NA          133.3333  NA       0.6666667

# but each element is a list
result['class', 'name']
result[1 ,1]
str(result) 

# `unlist` loses row/col names
test = matrix( unlist(result), ncol = ncol(df), byrow = T)
test

# this makes 1D data frame
test1 = do.call(rbind.data.frame, result)
test
```

Anybody know why a vector can be arranged as 2D like above? Is it the effect of attributes?

And how can we fix the result of `sapply(df, f1)`? It looks so close to the correct result.

Thanks!

Comment: `Reduce(cbind,list)`

Comment: @MichaelChirico I would use `do.call` over `Reduce` as the former is faster.  To the OP: You may need an `if` `else` condition to not return the warning for columns that are not numeric.

Comment: It is better to use `lapply` than `sapply`. but if you really wanted use `simplify=FALSE`, i.e. `str(do.call(rbind.data.frame,sapply(df, f1, simplify=FALSE)))`

Comment: nice thanks @MichaelChirico! Thanks @akrun yeah I do have `if` `else` in my practical function, min(factor) will even yield error.