# Separating an item into separate columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, organization

You have a column with the following items:

```
df <- data.frame(X1=c('abc','abc','xbc','xbc','ayc','ayc','abz','abz'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Output:

```
   X1
1 abc
2 abc
3 xbc
4 xbc
5 ayc
6 ayc
7 abz
8 abz
```

How do you separate the items so that each letter now constitutes a new item in a separate column?

Example:

```
   X1  X2  X3  X4
1 abc  a   b   c
2 abc  a   b   c
3 xbc  x   b   c
4 xbc  x   b   c
5 ayc  a   y   c
6 ayc  a   y   c
7 abz  a   b   z
8 abz  a   b   z
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you already search through the other 50 million questions just like this one and not find an answer?

Comment: Your example data doesn't contain strings (see `str(yourdf$X1)`).

Comment: Hi Glen, I do not understand the importance of what you're saying. Can you please clarify?

Comment: When you create the data frame, you need to include the argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to ensure that strings are encoded as strings, rather than as factors.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @RichardScriven given that it's actually hard to find (I know how to do it and *I* can't find a duplicate post, though I am sure there will be several) it would be more helpful if you located a duplicate than simply said "go search". It's non-trivial for a beginner.

Comment: One option is to use e.g. `strsplit(df[,1],split=")` and then turn the list into a data frame (e.g. like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame)).

Comment: Search `[r] split column` for 2055 results.  From the answers in the linked duplicate, just change the delimiter from `"|"` to `""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since I couldn't locate a duplicate with five minutes (actually, nearer to ten now) of searching, here goes.

If you fix up your data frame correctly, this gets you most of the way:

```
data.frame(mydf$X1,t(simplify2array(strsplit(mydf$X1,""))))
```

However if your real problem has a really large number of rows, using "t()" may be a bad way to do it.