# How to make format clean and elegant after casting list to data.frame?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, coercion

I have set of vector in the list. I want to cast my list to data.frame object for fast manipulation. There is already solution for casting list to data.frame in this site. However, I tried this solution, it works good but format is bit of mass, not perfectly formatted. Can anyone propose any idea to make casting result more clean/ elegant? How can make this happen efficiently ?

mini example

```
myList <- list(
  a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
  b = c(1,1,1,2,0,3,4),
  c = c(1,2,4,4,5,0,6)
)
```

I used following solution:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(myList, data.frame, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

my desired output

```
output <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
  b = c(1,1,1,2,0,3,4),
  c = c(1,2,4,4,5,0,6))
```

How can I get my expected output? Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't `list(a <- 1)`, rather `list(a = 1)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R list to data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame)

Comment: because akrun' solution is interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to convert to `data.table`, use `setDT` directly on the `list`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(myList)[]
#   a b c
#1: 1 1 1
#2: 2 1 2
#3: 3 1 4
#4: 4 2 4
#5: 5 0 5
#6: 6 3 0
#7: 7 4 6
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work?

```
output <- data.frame(myList)
colnames(output) <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: could you make it more general instead of indicating name of vector in the list manually ?

Comment: You don't need to name `output` separately, the names will be brought across from `myList` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should use cbind instead of rbind and set data frame names.

```
output <- do.call(cbind,lapply(myList,data.frame, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
names(output) <- c("a","b","c")
```