# Create a data fram from lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have 3 lists and I would like to combine them into a dataframe, where each column is an element of a list.

There are the 3 lists (ld is a nummeric with value 112)

```
ld <- 112

# 3 lists
or <- as.list(rep(0, 8))
thetax <- lapply(0:7, function(x) ld * cos (x * pi / 4))
thetay <- lapply(0:7, function(x) ld * sin (x * pi / 4))
```

Here is my attempt to combine them into a data.frame

```
 df3 <- data.frame(or, thetax, thetay)
```

I think this should be very simple and basic but I can't do it.

I have been searching for the answer for hours this and have been trying different things but nothing seems to work so far, and I can't execute it.

Comment: The `ld` is not shown.  So, perhaps `data.frame(or  = unlist(or), thetax = unlist(thetax), thetay = unlist(thetay))`

Comment: Your example fails `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'ld' not found` - you need to provide `ld`.

Comment: Do these need to be lists at all? I can't see the reason you're working with lists instead of vectors. Vectors would be faster and tidier.

Comment: Relavant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame

Comment: Could also do `data.frame(sapply(list(or, thetax, thetay), unlist))` if you don't have mixed types there

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding about 'ld'. I wrote on the questions that " (ld is a nummeric with value 112)", but I understand that is very visible.

Comment: What is your desired output? You want the columns in the data.frame to remain lists? Why would you want to store them in a data.frame then? Why not in a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you can't create `data.frame`s with list columns is a longstanding annoyance.  In decreasing order of preference, you can either

- Use `data_frame` from the `tibble` package instead.

  ```
  tibble::data_frame(or, thetax, thetay)
  ```
- Create a list with dimensions, then convert that to be a data frame, as suggested by David Arenburg.

  ```
  data.frame(cbind(or, thetax, thetay))
  ```
- Create the data frame, then add the list columns afterwards.

  ```
  df3 <- data.frame(1:8)[,FALSE]
  df3$or <- or
  df3$or <- thetax
  df3$or <- thetay
  ```
- Use `structure` to make the data frame.

  ```
  structure(
    list(or, thetax, thetay), 
    class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = .set_row_names(8)
  )
  ```

Comment: See my answer below for a straightforward way to create data.frame columns from lists.

Comment: Nevermind, @David Arenburg pointed me out this produces lists within data.frames...

Comment: If OP wants to keep them as lists, you could just do `data.frame(cbind(or, thetax, thetay))` I guess. Though I fail to understand why to convert this into a `data.frame` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something, but I would think this will work as vectors instead of lists. Does this work for you, or am I way off target?

```
x <- 0:7
ld <- 112
or <- rep(0, 8)
thetax <- ld * cos (x * pi / 4)
thetay <- ld * sin (x * pi / 4)
df3 <- data.frame( or, thetax, thetay )
```

Comment: Yes, it would work with vectors instead of lists (which are also vectors btw). But the problem they have lists

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I have lists

Answer (score 1):

I realize you already accepted an answer, however it is not true that there is no easy way to create a data.frame from lists.
A straightforward way using your example is:

```
ld <- 112
or <- as.list(rep(0, 8))
thetax <- lapply(0:7, function(x) ld * cos (x * pi / 4))
thetay <- lapply(0:7, function(x) ld * sin (x * pi / 4))

df <- as.data.frame(do.call("cbind",list(or, thetax, thetay)))
df

  V1            V2           V3
1  0           112            0
2  0      79.19596     79.19596
3  0  6.858022e-15          112
4  0     -79.19596     79.19596
5  0          -112 1.371604e-14
6  0     -79.19596    -79.19596
7  0 -2.057407e-14         -112
8  0      79.19596    -79.19596
```

Comment: And now for the fun part- checking results. Please run `str(df)`

Comment: On second thought, maybe that's what OP actually want, dunno

Comment: this is not exactly what I wanted, but thank you for the insight.

Comment: Btw, you can just do `data.frame(cbind(or, thetax, thetay))` if OP just wants to keep them as list column