# transform "mFilter" object (list of Time-Series) to plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, list, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I'm working with the `hpfilter` from the `mFilter` package and I can't seem to find a simple way to convert the list of *Time-Series* objects by `hpfilter` to a format I can use with ggplot2. I realize I can take it all apart and put it back together, but I imagine there's some simple way I have overlooked? I tried the code suggested in the SO discussion *[R list to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame)*. However I couldn't find a way to convert the list of *Time-Series* objects to a `data.frame` in any simple way. The final goal is to reproduce the default plot produced by the `mFilter` object (see below)

Here's some example code

```
# install.packages(c("mFilter"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(mFilter)
data(unemp)
unemp.hp <- hpfilter(unemp, type=c("lambda"), freq = 1606)
# str(unemp.hp)
class(unemp.hp)
# [1] "mFilter"
plot(unemp.hp)
Hit <Return> to see next plot:
```

Also, why am I asked to " Hit `<Return>`" to see the plot?

[image: default plot produced by the <code>mFilter</code> object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plot` function calls `plot.mFilter` which has parameter `ask=interactive()` and it is set as `TRUE` for interactive sessions, 
    you could disable this by `ask=FALSE` in call for `plot`

```
plot(unemp.hp,ask=FALSE)
```

**Data:**

```
library(mFilter)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
# library(zoo)


data(unemp)
unemp.hp <- hpfilter(unemp, type=c("lambda"), freq = 1606)
# str(unemp.hp)
class(unemp.hp)
# [1] "mFilter"
plot(unemp.hp,ask=FALSE)
```

To check for slots of object `unemp.hp`

```
names(unemp.hp)
# [1] "cycle"   "trend"   "fmatrix" "title"   "xname"   "call"    "type"    "lambda"  "method" 
#[10] "x"
```

The relevant objects are `x` (the main unemp series) , `trend` and `cycle`. All three objects are of class `ts`, we first convert them to 
    data.frame using custom function and plot using `ggplot` and `gridExtra` (for `grid.arrange`)

```
objectList = list(unemp.hp$x,unemp.hp$trend,unemp.hp$cycle)
names(objectList) = c("unemp","trend","cycle")


sapply(objectList,class)
#unemp trend cycle 
# "ts"  "ts"  "ts"
```

**Conversion from ts to data.frame:**

```
fn_ts_to_DF = function(x)  {

DF = data.frame(date=zoo::as.Date(time(objectList[[x]])),tseries=as.matrix(objectList[[x]])) 
colnames(DF)[2]=names(objectList)[x]
return(DF)
}


DFList=lapply(seq_along(objectList),fn_ts_to_DF)
names(DFList) = c("unemp","trend","cycle")

seriesTrend = merge(DFList$unemp,DFList$trend,by="date")
cycleSeries = DFList$cycle
```

**Plots:**

```
gSeries = ggplot(melt(seriesTrend,"date"),aes(x=date,y=value,color=variable)) + geom_line() +
          ggtitle('Hodrick-Prescot Filter for unemp') + 
          theme(legend.title = element_blank(),legend.justification = c(0.1, 0.8), legend.position = c(0, 1),
          legend.direction = "horizontal",legend.background = element_rect(fill="transparent",size=.5, linetype="dotted"))
gCycle = ggplot(cycleSeries,aes(x=date,y=cycle)) + geom_line(color="#619CFF") + ggtitle("Cyclical component (deviations from trend)")

gComb = grid.arrange(gSeries,gCycle,nrow=2)
```

[image]

Comment: impressive! Looked really great! I do however get an error message when I run your function. Specifically I get `Error in as.Date.default(time(objectList[[x]])) : 
  do not know how to convert 'time(objectList[[x]])' to class “Date”` when I run the `DFList=lapply(seq_along(objectList),fn_ts_to_DF)` line. Did I overlook something? I will take another look at it when I'm less tired. Again, thanks!

Comment: Could you please check the output  of `time` in R session, which package does it refer to. By default, it is referenced from `stats` package i.e. [manual page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/time.html)

Comment: Yes, it's `namespace:stats` What should it be? Also, thank you for your prompt response!

Comment: It should refer to `stats` thanks, could you check output for `time(objectList[[1]])`

Comment: Worked like a charm, I have restarted R. It might be it. I am sorry I did not figure that out myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the prior answer, didn't worked for me.

I was getting the trend and cycle from a GDP quarterly series.

This data was a time series, so I did this, and worked for me:

```
list <- list(gdp_ln$x, gdp_ln$trend, gdp_ln$cycle)

names(list)=c("gdp","trend","cycle")

gdp<- data.frame((sapply(list,c)))
```

Data:

```
> dput(gdp_ln)
structure(c(16.0275785360442, 16.0477176062761, 16.0718936895007, 
16.0899963371452, 16.0875707712141, 16.0981391378223, 16.0988601288276, 
16.1110815092797, 16.1244321329861, 16.1384685077996, 16.1451472350838, 
16.148178781735, 16.161163569502, 16.1418894206861, 16.1634877625667, 
16.1965372621761, 16.2216815829736, 16.2387677536829, 16.249412380526, 
16.2690521777631, 16.2812185880068, 16.2951024427095, 16.2964024092233, 
16.3127733881018, 16.3233290487177, 16.3369922768377, 16.3486515031696, 
16.3489275708763, 16.3451264371757, 16.3524856433069, 16.3666338513045, 
16.3801691039135, 16.3959993202765, 16.4135937981601, 16.4321203154987, 
16.4488104165345, 16.4344524213544, 16.4302554348621, 16.4240722287677, 
16.425087582257, 16.4350803035092, 16.4507216431126, 16.4670532627455, 
16.4985227751756, 16.5094864456079, 16.5352746165004, 16.5504689966469, 
16.5594976247513, 16.5754312535087, 16.592641573353, 16.6003340665324, 
16.6063100774853, 16.6163655606058, 16.6370227688187, 16.6564363783854, 
16.6577160570216, 16.6543595214556, 16.6773721241902, 16.6911082706925, 
16.6935398489076, 16.6956102943815, 16.6798673418354, 16.6772670544553, 
16.6678707780266, 16.6606889172344, 16.6678398460835, 16.6668473810049, 
16.676020524389, 16.6775934319312, 16.6882821147755, 16.6957985899994, 
16.7032334217472, 16.6926036544774, 16.7027214366522, 16.7103625977254, 
16.7105344224572, 16.7042504851486, 16.7063913529457, 16.7100598555556, 
16.6960591147037, 16.686477079594, 16.5740423808036, 16.6181175035946
), .Tsp = c(2000, 2020.5, 4), class = "ts")
```