# Convert a list of character vectors into dataframe

Tags: r

my output a looks like:

```
str(a)
List of 8883695
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "ACCRUALS"
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "ACCRUALS"
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "ACCRUALS"
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "ACCRUALS"
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "ACCRUALS"
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "ACCRUALS"
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "ACCRUALS"
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "ACCRUALS"
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "ACCRUALS"
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "ACCRUALS"
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "ACCRUALS"
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "ACCRUALS"
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "AE"
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "AE"
 $ : chr [1:3] "20MICRONS" "A" "AE"
```

I want to convert this into a dataframe like:

ticker       frequency field

20MICRONS      A         ACCRUALS
20MICRONS      A         ACCRUALS
20MICRONS      A         AE
20MICRONS      A         AE
20MICRONS      A         AE
20MICRONS      A         AE

I have tried this:

```
b <- as.data.frame(a)  
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

But not working. Please help. I am new to R and stack overflow.

Comment: Step 1. Make a *smaller* example to test your code on. You've got 8 million of these.

Answer (score 4):

The `list` elements are not of `equal` length.  So, we need to convert it to equal `length` by padding with `NA`

```
mx <- max(lengths(a))
d1 <- data.frame(lapply(a, `length<-`, mx))
```

Comment: @shivrajgondi  This does correct it automatically by assigning elements that have less than the maximum length to pad with as many NAs to get all of them having the same length

Comment: Thanks Akrun, found certain vectors to be of length 4.

Comment: @shivrajgondi  Your partial `str` output suggests the length as 3, may be it is 4 based on the full `str`

Comment: This is a very cool answer, it sparked for me a followup quesiton on replacement functions I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69485776/why-dont-lambda-functions-handle-replacement-functions-in-their-intuitive-form

Answer (score 1):

I found a function called `do.call(rbind.data.frame, your_list)` - seems like this is what you're looking for. Check the comments section of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame).

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

a <- list(c("20M1", "A1", "ACC1"), 
          c("20M2", "A2", "ACC2"), 
          c("20M3"), 
          c("20M4", "A3"))

if_null_na <- function(x){
  if(is.null(x)) return(NA)
  x
}

a %>% 
  transpose() %>% 
  map(~map(.x, if_null_na)) %>% 
  map(unlist) %>% 
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique")
#> Warning: Element 3 must be length 3, not 1
#> Warning: Element 4 must be length 3, not 2
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> * `` -> ...2
#> * `` -> ...3
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   ...1  ...2  ...3 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 20M1  A1    ACC1 
#> 2 20M2  A2    ACC2 
#> 3 20M3  <NA>  <NA> 
#> 4 20M4  A3    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Though this way is much slower than Akrun's approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Reduce(rbind, a)`, which is handy for that.