# Merge 2 vectors with different lengths into a data frame

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, merge, sql-server-2016

I'd have to say that I've just started working with R half an hour ago, running R scripts from SQL Server, so I'm what they call a complete noob.

I'm trying to merge two R vectors into a data frame, but my problem is that the vectors have varying lengths.

I'm not sure if this can be done, although i don't necessarily see why not?

My R script is:

```
n <- c(2, 3, 5, 6);
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc");
df = data.frame(n, s);
```

And the error that I'm getting is:

> Error in data.frame(n, s) :    arguments imply differing number of
>   rows: 4, 3 Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> data.frame
>
> Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information. Error in
>   eval(expr, envir, enclos) :    Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for
>   more information. Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval ->
>   .Call Execution halted

Esentially what I'm imagining doing is generating a result set similar to a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
2    aa
3    bb
5    cc
6    NULL
```

I'm asking myself if I should specify a "replace NULL" values in the R data frame, but I'm not sure if this is a solution.

Comment: You can't have `NULL` there, but rather `NA` (for missing): `L = list(n = n, s = s); data.frame(lapply(L, \`length<-\`, max(lengths(L))))`. I guess there are a few dupes for this.

Comment: what you are refering to is not `merging`. To `merge` you need a key. It is not possible to combine `list` of different lengths into a data.frame in R. You have to make them the same length to combine them. How to you want to combine them?

Comment: @DJJ I was looking online to see if a R dataframe has an implicit key generated for each row so that I can `JOIN` or map them, but I couldn't find anything (yet).

Comment: You can build your own key and use the function `merge`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys! This clears things up a bit

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43159384/convert-a-list-of-character-vectors-into-dataframe/43159405#43159405

Comment: The provided dups are talking about `list` while this question talks about `vector`. I voted for reopen.

Comment: @Frank I'll be following your [R tutorial](http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/index.html) and hopefully you won't need to close these kind of dup-questions.

Comment: I was in the way of answering this when it was mark as a duplicate..... you can cbind your vector but then you will encounter the recycling rule. So you need to specify the lenght of your vector .... n <- max(length(d), length(e))
    length(d) <- n                      
    length(e) <- n
    m <- cbind(d,e)

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm very curious.

Comment: However , you need to understand that in R everything is a function and the data.frame function requires same lenght attributes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365885/combining-vectors-of-unequal-length-into-a-data-frame?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Cool, let me know how it goes. There's the R chat room if you have any comments or suggestions http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public The downvote is probably coming from people who think you should have found the dupe on your own (not me in this case). (Btw, I added Nico's link to the dupe target list.)

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the additional info! I guess dupes were to be likely in this basic-type scenario, but with a limited context and knowledge of R like mine it seems a bit *"unfair"*. Although I did take the time to look at the Stackoverflow suggested questions to see if the problems were similar (but they weren't).

Comment: Thank you @NicoCoallier! I'll be sure to follow all your links! I'm in the state of trying to find out about R and understand as much as possible, so every comment is a mini-gold-mine for me.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I am currently working on a R formation ...It is currently only in french but have a look at the script you'll get a good understanding of the data type and format.... https://github.com/NicoCoallier/Formation_R/blob/master/Operation_de_base.R  I'll make a English one soon :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one maybe:

```
sq <- seq(max(length(n), length(s)))
data.frame(n[sq], s[sq])

#  n.sq. s.sq.
#1     2    aa
#2     3    bb
#3     5    cc
#4     6  <NA>
```

Comment: I'm liking this! Thanks a lot!