# Is there a way other than below to load a json.rows file into RStudio?

Tags: json, r, data-import

I have a json.rows file -> instances.json.rows with approximately 223k rows

I tried using jsonlite and came up with

`instancesfile <- fromJSON("instances.json.rows")`

But i kept getting an error

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: trailing garbage
      kcBy-cs", "time_type": "in"} {"cluster_ids": ["Bz4SOc6zZn0"]
                 (right here) ------^
```

Here is an image of the data from the first row of my file. Apologies if my question is not clear enough. Let me know in the comments and I will edit my question as required. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: I think you need to replace newlines with , and wrap your whole file in a pair of {}... I am guessing that the file you are working with is actually a bunch of json statements separated by newlines, rather than a single unified statement.

Comment: Hi, yes. Each line of the file is a single JSON document that describes a single event or entity.
I'm new to working with json files. Could you please answer in detail on how i can load it into Rstudio ? Or point me to material i can read up if you don't have the time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
out <- lapply(readLines("instances.json.rows"), fromJSON)
```

Congrats out is what you want it to be. The L apply applies the fromJSON function to each member returned from readLines and returns the results to out. I miss Spoke a bit in my comment, to make your file valid json you would have to replace the newlines with comma, then put the result where the * is in the below example. But that's all non-sense, just use the above one liner.

```
{"data":[*]}
```

Comment: That definitely worked and helped me read the json file into my studio. But I now have a really long list which i cannot analyze. Any tips on how I can go ahead with that ? Would you mind if i sent you an email with screenshots of the list? Thank you!

Comment: What if you cast your long list to a data frame, could you get it done? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame

Answer (score 5):

```
library(jsonlite)
instancesfile <- stream_in(file("instances.json.rows"))
```

Advantages:

- Formats automatically as a data frame
- Gives verbose progress reports (unless you change the default)
- Let's you adjust the pagesize

Comment: It works nice! thanks @Jeff Parker