# How to read multiple csv files and combine them into a single dataframe

Tags: r

I'm using R. I have very many files in .csv format which I would like to read and then combine them into a data frame with each file representing a column, so that I can manipulate using simple statistics. How can I go about this?

Comment: Once you imported the files, follow [R - list to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `files` contains the list of your files,

```
ff <- sapply(files, read.csv)
df <- Reduce(cbind, ff)
```

First command loads all files. Second command merges all files into one data frame. Clearly, I am assuming that all files have one column and the same number of rows. You can check that with

```
sapply(ff, nrow)
sapply(ff, ncol)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Data<-do.call(rbind,lapply(filelist,read.csv))
```