# How to convert the items of a list column into their own columns to find cosine similarity in R?

Tags: r, list, cosine-similarity, doc2vec

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(id = 1:10,
               vectors = list(rnorm(25)))

# A tibble: 25 x 2
      id vectors   
   <int> <list>    
 1     1 <dbl [25]>
 2     2 <dbl [25]>
 3     3 <dbl [25]>
 4     4 <dbl [25]>
 5     5 <dbl [25]>
 6     6 <dbl [25]>
 7     7 <dbl [25]>
 8     8 <dbl [25]>
 9     9 <dbl [25]>
10    10 <dbl [25]>
```

I'd like to use this data set to find cosine similarity where each row represents a document.  The `cosine` function from the `lsa` package seems like a good/easy way to do this, however I would need each document represented as a column.  I'd like to simply to do `data %>% t()` to get my desired result, but that's not working.  I've also tried "spreading" the list column first using `unest` and `spread`.  I've also tried `flatten` to no avail.  The first line of my desired output would look something like:

```
  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
0.1  0.3  0.7  0.3  0.1  0.1  0.3  0.7  0.3  0.1
```

If there's a function from another package that handles data in this format I would by all means just use that instead though at this point I would like to figure this out from a curiosity standpoint.  I've looked at [R - list to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame), but I'm not sure how I can apply that to this situation.

The background to this is that I've performed doc2vec in python with gensim but do to our environment in work, if I want to build something interactive for a client it would need to be in R.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - list to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
mutate(data,vectors=sapply(vectors, function(x) paste(x,collapse=","))) %>% 
    separate_rows(vectors,sep=",") %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(numb=row_number(),vectors=as.numeric(vectors)) %>%
    spread(key=numb,value=vectors)

# A tibble: 10 x 26
# Groups:   id [10]
      id   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`    `5`   `6`    `7`   `8`     `9`  `10`  `11`  `12`   `13`   `14`  `15`   `16`
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1  1.46 0.140 0.209 -3.04 -0.487 -1.09 0.0579  1.10 -0.0256 0.515 0.990 0.303 -0.930 0.0840 0.527 0.0159
 2     2  1.46 0.140 0.209 -3.04 -0.487 -1.09 0.0579  1.10 -0.0256 0.515 0.990 0.303 -0.930 0.0840 0.527 0.0159
 3     3  1.46 0.140 0.209 -3.04 -0.487 -1.09 0.0579  1.10 -0.0256 0.515 0.990 0.303 -0.930 0.0840 0.527 0.0159
 4     4  1.46 0.140 0.209 -3.04 -0.487 -1.09 0.0579  1.10 -0.0256 0.515 0.990 0.303 -0.930 0.0840 0.527 0.0159
 5     5  1.46 0.140 0.209 -3.04 -0.487 -1.09 0.0579  1.10 -0.0256 0.515 0.990 0.303 -0.930 0.0840 0.527 0.0159
 6     6  1.46 0.140 0.209 -3.04 -0.487 -1.09 0.0579  1.10 -0.0256 0.515 0.990 0.303 -0.930 0.0840 0.527 0.0159
 7     7  1.46 0.140 0.209 -3.04 -0.487 -1.09 0.0579  1.10 -0.0256 0.515 0.990 0.303 -0.930 0.0840 0.527 0.0159
 8     8  1.46 0.140 0.209 -3.04 -0.487 -1.09 0.0579  1.10 -0.0256 0.515 0.990 0.303 -0.930 0.0840 0.527 0.0159
 9     9  1.46 0.140 0.209 -3.04 -0.487 -1.09 0.0579  1.10 -0.0256 0.515 0.990 0.303 -0.930 0.0840 0.527 0.0159
10    10  1.46 0.140 0.209 -3.04 -0.487 -1.09 0.0579  1.10 -0.0256 0.515 0.990 0.303 -0.930 0.0840 0.527 0.0159
# ... with 9 more variables: `17` <dbl>, `18` <dbl>, `19` <dbl>, `20` <dbl>, `21` <dbl>, `22` <dbl>, `23` <dbl>,
#   `24` <dbl>, `25` <dbl>
```

I find it's easiest to spread data by first gathering it into a long-data format. We achieve that using `separate_rows`. The problem there is that we first need to transform the lists in vectors into something `separate_rows` can work with. We do that using `paste` with `collapse=","` within a sapply (otherwise all the lists will be pasted together).

Once we have that it's just a matter of grouping, adding a row-index column (and transforming the numbers back to numeric), and spreading to achieve the desired format.

Comment: Thanks, only issue I see is that this gets rid of the negative numbers

Comment: Fixed the issue in my answer. Now negatives are preserved.