# Identify and count spells (Distinctive events within each group)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time-series, grouping

I'm looking for an efficient way to identify spells/runs in a time series. In the image below, the first three columns is what I have, the fourth column, `spell` is what I'm trying to compute. I've tried using `dplyr`'s `lead` and `lag`, but that gets too complicated. I've tried `rle` but got nowhere.

[image]

**ReprEx**

```
df <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1538876340, 1538876400, 
1538876460,1538876520, 1538876580, 1538876640, 1538876700, 1538876760, 1526824800, 
1526824860, 1526824920, 1526824980, 1526825040, 1526825100), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), is.5 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

I prefer a `tidyverse` solution.

**Assumptions**

1. Data is sorted by `group` and then by `time`
2. There are no gaps in `time` within each group

## Update

Thanks for the contributions. I've timed some of the proposed approaches on the full data (n=2,583,360)

1. the `rle` approach by @markus took 0.53 seconds
2. the `cumsum` approach by @M-M took 2.85 seconds
3. the function approach by @MrFlick took 0.66 seconds
4. the `rle` and `dense_rank` by @tmfmnk took 0.89

I ended up choosing (1) by @markus because it's fast and still somewhat intuitive (subjective). (2) by @M-M best satisfied my desire for a `dplyr` solution, though it is computationally inefficient.

Comment: For someone who is not familiar with how the `spell` is computed, can you share a formula or description?

Comment: @nsinghs I think they mean "hospital spell"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option using `rle`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(
    spell = {
      r <- rle(is.5)
      r$values <- cumsum(r$values) * r$values
      inverse.rle(r) 
      }
  )
# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   group [2]
#   time                group  is.5 spell
#   <dttm>              <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2018-10-07 01:39:00 A         0     0
# 2 2018-10-07 01:40:00 A         1     1
# 3 2018-10-07 01:41:00 A         1     1
# 4 2018-10-07 01:42:00 A         0     0
# 5 2018-10-07 01:43:00 A         1     2
# 6 2018-10-07 01:44:00 A         0     0
# 7 2018-10-07 01:45:00 A         0     0
# 8 2018-10-07 01:46:00 A         1     3
# 9 2018-05-20 14:00:00 B         0     0
#10 2018-05-20 14:01:00 B         0     0
#11 2018-05-20 14:02:00 B         1     1
#12 2018-05-20 14:03:00 B         1     1
#13 2018-05-20 14:04:00 B         0     0
#14 2018-05-20 14:05:00 B         1     2
```

---

You asked for a `tidyverse` solution but if speed is your concern, you might use `data.table`. The syntax is very similar

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, spell := {
  r <- rle(is.5)
  r$values <- cumsum(r$values) * r$values
  inverse.rle(r) 
  }, by = group][] # the [] at the end prints the data.table
```

**explanation**

When we call

```
r <- rle(df$is.5)
```

the result we get is

```
r
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:10] 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1
#  values : num [1:10] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

We need to replace `values` with the cumulative sum where `values == 1` while `values` should remain zero otherwise.

We can achieve this when we multiple `cumsum(r$values)` with `r$values`; where the latter is a vector of `0`s and `1`s.

```
r$values <- cumsum(r$values) * r$values
r$values
# [1] 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5
```

Finally we call `inverse.rle` to get back a vector of the same length as `is.5`.

```
inverse.rle(r)
# [1] 0 1 1 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 4 4 0 5
```

We do this for every `group`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a helper function that can return what you are after

```
spell_index <- function(time, flag) {
  change <- time-lag(time)==1 & flag==1 & lag(flag)!=1
  cumsum(change) * (flag==1)+0
}
```

And you can use it with your data like

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(
    spell = spell_index(time, is.5)
  )
```

Basically the helper functions uses `lag()` to look for changes. We use `cumsum()` to increment the number of changes. Then we multiply by a boolean value so zero-out the values you want to be zeroed out.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `rleid` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'group', get the run-length-id (`rleid`) of 'is.5' and multiply with the values of 'is.5' so as to replace the ids corresponding to 0s in is.5 to 0, assign it to 'spell', then specify the `i` with a logical vector to select rows that have 'spell' values not zero, `match` those values of 'spell' with `unique` 'spell' and assign it to 'spell'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, spell := rleid(is.5) * as.integer(is.5), group
       ][!!spell, spell := match(spell, unique(spell))][]
#                   time group is.5 spell
# 1: 2018-10-07 01:39:00     A    0     0
# 2: 2018-10-07 01:40:00     A    1     1
# 3: 2018-10-07 01:41:00     A    1     1
# 4: 2018-10-07 01:42:00     A    0     0
# 5: 2018-10-07 01:43:00     A    1     2
# 6: 2018-10-07 01:44:00     A    0     0
# 7: 2018-10-07 01:45:00     A    0     0
# 8: 2018-10-07 01:46:00     A    1     3
# 9: 2018-05-20 14:00:00     B    0     0
#10: 2018-05-20 14:01:00     B    0     0
#11: 2018-05-20 14:02:00     B    1     1
#12: 2018-05-20 14:03:00     B    1     1
#13: 2018-05-20 14:04:00     B    0     0
#14: 2018-05-20 14:05:00     B    1     2
```

---

Or after the first step, use `.GRP`

```
df[!!spell, spell := .GRP, spell]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works,

The data,

```
df <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1538876340, 1538876400, 1538876460,1538876520, 1538876580, 1538876640, 1538876700, 1538876760, 1526824800, 1526824860, 1526824920, 1526824980, 1526825040, 1526825100), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), is.5 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

We split our data by group,

```
df2 <- split(df, df$group)
```

Build a function we can apply to the list,

```
my_func <- function(dat){
  rst <- dat %>% 
    mutate(change = diff(c(0,is.5))) %>% 
    mutate(flag = change*abs(is.5)) %>% 
    mutate(spell = ifelse(is.5 == 0 | change == -1, 0, cumsum(flag))) %>% 
    dplyr::select(time, group, is.5, spell)
  return(rst)
}
```

Then apply it,

```
l <- lapply(df2, my_func)
```

We can now turn this [list back into a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4227483/9555388):

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, l)
```

Answer (score 1):

A somehow different possibility (not involving `cumsum()`) could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(group) %>%
 mutate(spell = with(rle(is.5), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 group_by(group, is.5) %>%
 mutate(spell = dense_rank(spell)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 mutate(spell = ifelse(is.5 == 0, 0, spell))

   time                group  is.5 spell
   <dttm>              <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2018-10-07 01:39:00 A         0     0
 2 2018-10-07 01:40:00 A         1     1
 3 2018-10-07 01:41:00 A         1     1
 4 2018-10-07 01:42:00 A         0     0
 5 2018-10-07 01:43:00 A         1     2
 6 2018-10-07 01:44:00 A         0     0
 7 2018-10-07 01:45:00 A         0     0
 8 2018-10-07 01:46:00 A         1     3
 9 2018-05-20 14:00:00 B         0     0
10 2018-05-20 14:01:00 B         0     0
11 2018-05-20 14:02:00 B         1     1
12 2018-05-20 14:03:00 B         1     1
13 2018-05-20 14:04:00 B         0     0
14 2018-05-20 14:05:00 B         1     2
```

Here it, first, groups by "group" and then gets the run-length-ID of "is.5". Second, it groups by "group" and "is.5" and ranks the values on the run-length-ID. Finally, it assigns 0 to rows where "is.5" == 0.

Answer (score 1):

One options is using `cumsum`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(group) %>%  arrange(group, time) %>% 
   mutate(spell = is.5 * cumsum( c(0,lag(is.5)[-1]) != is.5 & is.5!=0) )


# # A tibble: 14 x 4
# # Groups:   group [2]
#   time                  group     is.5   spell
#   <dttm>                <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 2018-10-07 01:39:00   A         0      0
# 2 2018-10-07 01:40:00   A         1      1
# 3 2018-10-07 01:41:00   A         1      1
# 4 2018-10-07 01:42:00   A         0      0
# 5 2018-10-07 01:43:00   A         1      2
# 6 2018-10-07 01:44:00   A         0      0
# 7 2018-10-07 01:45:00   A         0      0
# 8 2018-10-07 01:46:00   A         1      3
# 9 2018-05-20 14:00:00   B         0      0
# 10 2018-05-20 14:01:00  B         0      0
# 11 2018-05-20 14:02:00  B         1      1
# 12 2018-05-20 14:03:00  B         1      1
# 13 2018-05-20 14:04:00  B         0      0
# 14 2018-05-20 14:05:00  B         1      2
```

`c(0,lag(is.5)[-1]) != is.5` this takes care of assigning a new id (i.e. `spell`) whenever `is.5` changes; but we want to avoid assigning new ones to those rows `is.5` equal to `0` and that's why I have the second rule in `cumsum` function (i.e. `(is.5!=0)`).

However, that second rule only prevents assigning a new id (adding 1 to the previous id) but it won't set the id to `0`. That's why I have multiplied the answer by `is.5`.