# Combine tidy text with synonyms to create dataframe

Tags: r, tidytext, qdap

**I have sample data frame as below:**

```
 quoteiD <- c("q1","q2","q3","q4", "q5")
 quote <- c("Unthinking respect for authority is the greatest enemy of truth.",
      "In the middle of difficulty lies opportunity.",
      "Intelligence is the ability to adapt to change.",
      "Science is not only a disciple of reason but, also, one of romance and passion.", 
      "If I have seen further it is by standing on the shoulders of Giants.")

 library(dplyr)
  quotes <- tibble(quoteiD = quoteiD, quote= quote)
   quotes
```

**I have created some tidy text as below**

```
library(tidytext)
 data(stop_words)
   tidy_words <- quotes %>%
      unnest_tokens(word, quote) %>%
        anti_join(stop_words) %>% 
         count( word, sort = TRUE)
tidy_words
```

**Further, I have searched the synonyms using *qdap* package as below**

```
 library(qdap)
  syns <- synonyms(tidy_words$word)
```

The qdap out put is a list , and I am looking to pick the first 5 synonym for each word in the tidy data frame and create a column called synonyms  as below:

```
word       n    synonyms
ability    1    adeptness, aptitude, capability, capacity, competence 
adapt      1    acclimatize, accommodate, adjust, alter, apply,
authority  1    ascendancy, charge, command, control, direction
```

**What is an elegant way of merging the list of 5 words from qdap synonym function and separate by commas?**

Comment: `syns %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  rename("Syn" = 1) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("Word_DefNumber") %>% 
  separate(Word_DefNumber, c("Word", "DefNumber"), sep = "\\.") %>% 
  mutate(DefNumber = as.numeric(gsub("def_", "", DefNumber))) %>%
  group_by(Word) %>% 
  slice(1:5) %>% 
  summarise(synonyms = paste(Syn, collapse = ", ")) `

Comment: @KerryJackson this works fine. thank you. Would you be kind enough to explain what it does? as well write it as an answer so that I accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way this can be done using a `tidyverse` solution is

```r
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:plyr':
#> 
#>     arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, rename, summarise,
#>     summarize
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidytext)
library(qdap)
#> Loading required package: qdapDictionaries
#> Loading required package: qdapRegex
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'qdapRegex'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     explain
#> Loading required package: qdapTools
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'qdapTools'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     id
#> The following object is masked from 'package:plyr':
#> 
#>     id
#> Loading required package: RColorBrewer
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'qdap'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     %>%
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     Filter
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidyr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:qdap':
#> 
#>     %>%

quotes <- tibble(quoteiD = paste0("q", 1:5), 
                 quote=  c(".\n\nthe ebodac consortium consists of partners: janssen (efpia), london school of hygiene and tropical medicine (lshtm),", 
                           "world vision) mobile health software development and deployment in resource limited settings grameen\n\nas such, the ebodac consortium is well placed to tackle.", 
                           "Intelligence is the ability to adapt to change.", 
                           "Science is a of reason of romance and passion.", 
                           "If I have seen further it is by standing on ."))
quotes
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   quoteiD quote                                                            
#>   <chr>   <chr>                                                            
#> 1 q1      ".\n\nthe ebodac consortium consists of partners: janssen (efpia~
#> 2 q2      "world vision) mobile health software development and deployment~
#> 3 q3      Intelligence is the ability to adapt to change.                  
#> 4 q4      Science is a of reason of romance and passion.                   
#> 5 q5      If I have seen further it is by standing on .

data(stop_words)
tidy_words <- quotes %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, quote) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words) %>% 
  count( word, sort = TRUE)
#> Joining, by = "word"
tidy_words
#> # A tibble: 33 x 2
#>    word            n
#>    <chr>       <int>
#>  1 consortium      2
#>  2 ebodac          2
#>  3 ability         1
#>  4 adapt           1
#>  5 change          1
#>  6 consists        1
#>  7 deployment      1
#>  8 development     1
#>  9 efpia           1
#> 10 grameen         1
#> # ... with 23 more rows

syns <- synonyms(tidy_words$word)
#> no match for the following:
#> consortium, ebodac, consists, deployment, efpia, grameen, janssen, london, lshtm, partners, settings, software, tropical
#> ========================

syns %>% 
  plyr::ldply(data.frame) %>% # Change the list to a dataframe (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame)
  rename("Word_DefNumber" = 1, "Syn" = 2) %>% # Rename the columns with a name that is more intuitive
  separate(Word_DefNumber, c("Word", "DefNumber"), sep = "\\.") %>% # Find the word part of the word and definition number
  group_by(Word) %>% # Group by words, so that when we select rows it is done for each word
  slice(1:5) %>% # Keep the first 5 rows for each word
  summarise(synonyms = paste(Syn, collapse = ", ")) %>% # Combine the synonyms together comma separated using paste 
  ungroup() # So there are not unintended effects of having the data grouped when using the data later
#> # A tibble: 20 x 2
#>    Word         synonyms                                                   
#>    <chr>        <chr>                                                      
#>  1 ability      adeptness, aptitude, capability, capacity, competence      
#>  2 adapt        acclimatize, accommodate, adjust, alter, apply             
#>  3 change       alter, convert, diversify, fluctuate, metamorphose         
#>  4 development  advance, advancement, evolution, expansion, growth         
#>  5 health       fitness, good condition, haleness, healthiness, robustness 
#>  6 hygiene      cleanliness, hygienics, sanitary measures, sanitation      
#>  7 intelligence acumen, alertness, aptitude, brain power, brains           
#>  8 limited      bounded, checked, circumscribed, confined, constrained     
#>  9 medicine     cure, drug, medicament, medication, nostrum                
#> 10 mobile       ambulatory, itinerant, locomotive, migrant, motile         
#> 11 passion      animation, ardour, eagerness, emotion, excitement          
#> 12 reason       apprehension, brains, comprehension, intellect, judgment   
#> 13 resource     ability, capability, cleverness, ingenuity, initiative     
#> 14 romance      affair, affaire (du coeur), affair of the heart, amour, at~
#> 15 school       academy, alma mater, college, department, discipline       
#> 16 science      body of knowledge, branch of knowledge, discipline, art, s~
#> 17 standing     condition, credit, eminence, estimation, footing           
#> 18 tackle       accoutrements, apparatus, equipment, gear, implements      
#> 19 vision       eyes, eyesight, perception, seeing, sight                  
#> 20 world        earth, earthly sphere, globe, everybody, everyone
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Please note that `plyr` should be loaded before `dplyr`

Comment: @Kelly Jackson 
I tried with another dataset where the quote variable is as below without success.
`quote <- c(".\n\nthe ebodac consortium consists of  partners: janssen (efpia), london school of hygiene and tropical medicine (lshtm),",
          "world vision) mobile health software development and deployment in resource limited settings grameen\n\nas such, the ebodac consortium is well placed to tackle.",
          "Intelligence is the ability to adapt to change.",
          "Science is  a of reason of romance and passion.", 
          "If I have seen further it is by standing on .")`

Comment: To be honest I am not sure exactly why but when the list was unlisted and changed to a dataframe, in one set of quotes the rownames were descriptive and in the other they were numbers.  I edited my answer to change the list to a dataframe in a different way.

Comment: @Kelly Jackson even with the previous data frame it gives the following error 

**Error in rename(., Word_DefNumber = 1, Syn = 2) : 
  unused arguments (Word_DefNumber = 1, Syn = 2)**

Comment: Try removing the ., in rename

Comment: I managed to remove by using ** dplyr::rename**

But I also noticed the slice does not capture the words with less than 5 synonyms, any insight on why this is the case?

Comment: If you had to put `dplyr::` before rename, then it suggests there are multiple commands for `rename` with different packages, so there are conflicts.  Please make sure you load `plyr` before `dplyr`.  As far as not capturing words with less than 5 synonyms, that is not the case for me, see hygiene which has 4.

Comment: ..thank you, it works fine. I have learnt a great deal with this problem.