# Identify missing values in an R data table

Tags: r

I want to identify missing values in an R data datable

In order to get the id, column "id" of each column in your dataset

I use `apply(is.na(dt_tb) 2, which)` this scrip tells me the position, I would like to replace the position by the id number (id column)

```
dt_tb <- data.table(id = c(5, 6, 7, 15),
                 coll = c("this", NA,"NA", "text"),
                 cyy = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),
                 hhh = c(2.5, 4.2, 3.2, NA),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

apply(is.na(dt_tb), 2, which)
```

example
$id
integer(0)

$coll
[1] 2

$cyy
integer(0)

$hhh
[1] 4

I want

id
integer(0)

coll
6  7

cyy
integer(0)

hhh
15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unlist` to get `id` from `dt_tb$id` and `relist` to come back to the origin structure.

```
i <- apply(is.na(dt_tb) | dt_tb=="NA", 2, which)
relist(dt_tb$id[unlist(i)], i)
#$id
#numeric(0)
#
#$coll
#[1] 6 7
#
#$cyy
#numeric(0)
#
#$hhh
#[1] 15
```

Comment: Thanks how I can return a dataframe or datatable

Comment: Have a look at: [Convert a list to a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4227223/10488504)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` to get row and column index where `NA` or `"NA"` is present. You can then use `split` to get a named list.

```
mat <- which(is.na(dt_tb) | dt_tb == 'NA', arr.ind = TRUE)
split(dt_tb$id[mat[, 1]], names(dt_tb)[mat[, 2]])

#$coll
#[1] 6 7

#$hhh
#[1] 15
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `complete.cases(dt_tb)`

```
install.packages("devtools")
install.packages("data.table")
library(devtools)
library(data.table)

dt_tb <- data.table(id = c(5, 6, 7, 15),
                    coll = c("this", NA,"NA", "text"),
                    cyy = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),
                    hhh = c(2.5, 4.2, 3.2, NA),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


complete.cases(dt_tb) # returns: TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

which(!complete.cases(dt_tb)) # return row numbers: 2 4

dt_tb[!complete.cases(dt_tb),] # returns: rows with missing data/na's
```

update:

```
dt_tb[which(!complete.cases(dt_tb)),1] #to return ID's

id
1:  6
2: 15
```