# How to turn a list with multiple number per line into a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list that looks like this

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 5 6
```

I would like to turn it into a data frame like this

```
   A B C
1  1 
2  2 3 4 
3  5 6
```

Sadly, I do not know how to do this.

Could anyone give me the answer, please? Thank you

Comment: I think [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/convert-a-list-to-a-data-frame) might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
data.frame(t(sapply(lst,`length<-`,max(lengths(lst)))))
```

or

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(lst,`length<-`,max(lengths(lst)))))
```

giving

```
  X1 X2 X3
1  1 NA NA
2  2  3  4
3  5  6 NA
```

**Data**

```
lst <- list(1, 2:4, 5:6)
```

---

## **Update**

It seems you have `NULL` in `lst`. In this case, you can try the code below

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(replace(lst,!lengths(lst),NA),`length<-`,max(lengths(lst)))))
```

or

```
data.frame(t(sapply(replace(lst,!lengths(lst),NA),`length<-`,max(lengths(lst)))))
```

---

**Example**
Given `lst` as

```
lst <- list(1,2:4,5:6,NULL,1:4)

> lst
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 5 6

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

we will get

```
> data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(replace(lst,!lengths(lst),NA),`length<-`,max(lengths(lst))))) 
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1 NA NA NA
2  2  3  4 NA
3  5  6 NA NA
4 NA NA NA NA
5  1  2  3  4

> data.frame(t(sapply(replace(lst,!lengths(lst),NA),`length<-`,max(lengths(lst)))))
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1 NA NA NA
2  2  3  4 NA
3  5  6 NA NA
4 NA NA NA NA
5  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: Thomas, so the `length<-` part makes the length of each vector in list 'lst' as 3, which is the max length of all vectors in that list?

Comment: @KarthikS Yes, you got it!

Comment: With the second option, it works but I have this error `1: In lapply(meps, `length<-`, max(lengths(meps))) :
  length of NULL cannot be changed
2: In lapply(meps, `length<-`, max(lengths(meps))) :
  length of NULL cannot be changed`

Comment: @JMCrocs It seems you have `NULL` in your list. Please see my update for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `dplyr` `bind_rows()` with this trick (I have used the data from **@ThomasIsCoding** many thanks):

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df <- bind_rows(lapply(lst,function(x)as.data.frame(t(x))))
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1 NA NA
2  2  3  4
3  5  6 NA
```