# Convert list to DataFrame using for LOOP

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops

I am trying to convert my list that has 48 components to a consolidated data frame
using the for loop:

```
df1 = as.data.frame(list[1])
df2 = as.data.frame(list[2])
df3 = as.data.frame(list[3])
.
.
.
df48 = as.data.frame(list[48])
```

```
library(dplyr)

bda <- bda %>% 
  select(UNIQUE_CODE) 

for (i in 1:length(mi_lista)) {
  bd <- as.data.frame(mi_lista[[i]])
  df <- left_join(bda, bd)
}
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Why is it necessary to use a loop? Can't you use any of [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/convert-a-list-to-a-data-frame)?

Comment: Cant really tell what you are trying to achieve. Probably you need to use `list2DF(your_list)`

Comment: Thanks for your contributions. I changed bda to df and the problem was solved