# How to convert this small list to dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have this small list:

```
my_list <- list(time = structure(c(0, 1), dim = 2:1, dimnames = list(c("Pre", 
"Post"), "Post")), treatment = structure(c(0, 1), dim = 2:1, dimnames = list(
    c("Control", "Treatment"), "Treatment")))

# that gives me: 
$time
     Post
Pre     0
Post    1

$treatment
          Treatment
Control           0
Treatment         1
```

I want to convert it to dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I have tried everything from this link, but it did not give me my desired df:
[Convert a list to a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/convert-a-list-to-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function how we can solve this task:

```
final_df <- do.call(cbind, lapply(names(my_list), function(name) {
  df <- as.data.frame(my_list[[name]])
  transformed_df <- apply(df, 2, function(y) paste(names(y), y, sep = " "))
  colnames(transformed_df) <- paste("Levels of", name)
  transformed_df
}))

final_df
```

```
  Levels of Time Levels of Treatment
1          Pre 0           Control 0
2         Post 1         Treatment 1
```

Here is the same procedure step by step:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(my_list[1]$time)
df2 <- as.data.frame(my_list[2]$treatment)

transformed_df1 <- apply(df1, 2, function(x) paste(names(x), x, sep = " "))
transformed_df1 <- as.data.frame(transformed_df1)
                    
transformed_df2 <- apply(df2, 2, function(x) paste(names(x), x, sep = " "))
transformed_df2 <- as.data.frame(transformed_df2)

final_df <- cbind(transformed_df1, transformed_df2)
colnames(final_df) <- c("Levels of Time", "Levels of Treatment")
final_df
```

Comment: Thank you,  fantastic step-by step solution.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve your problem:

```
df = Reduce(cbind, lapply(my_list, \(x) data.frame(rownames(x), x, row.names=NULL)))

#   rownames.x. Post rownames.x. Treatment
# 1         Pre    0     Control         0
# 2        Post    1   Treatment         1
```

You need to rename the columns as you prefer

`my_list` is a list of on-column matrices with row names.
`\(x) data.frame(rownames(x), x, row.names=NULL)` is a function that creates a data.frame where the first column is the row names of the matrix and the second is the data in the matrix. `lapply` function allows to apply this logic to each matrix in `my_list` and return the result in a new list. And `Reduce` allows to cumulatively bind the data frames obtained with `lapply` using `cbind` to create a new data.drame.

Comment: Where are Control and Treatment ?

Comment: Check and let me know if it's ok

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, this is very good, could you please elaborate a bit what is happening in this code ?

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation, I upvoted your answer as good one-liner solution.